# Equivalent of *Nix 'which' command in PowerShell?

Tags: unix, powershell, command

How do I ask PowerShell where something is?

For instance, "which notepad" and it returns the directory where the notepad.exe is run from according to the current paths.

Comment: [PowerShell equivalent to the Unix `which` command?](https://superuser.com/q/34492/241386)

Answer (score 505, accepted):

The very first alias I made once I started customizing my profile in PowerShell was 'which'.

```sh
New-Alias which get-command
```

To add this to your profile, type this:

```sh
"`nNew-Alias which get-command" | add-content $profile
```

The `n at the start of the last line is to ensure it will start as a new line.

Comment: You can put it in your profile script.  More on profiles - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613488(VS.85).aspx

Comment: i like running: `Get-Command <command> | Format-Table Path, Name` so i can get the path where the command sits too.

Comment: Is there any way to have the path all the time without to type '| Format-Table Path, Name' ?

Comment: In previous versions, Get-Command didn't provide sorted output. It does now. This is clearly the right answer today ;-)

Comment: If you are planning to use this in a script then there are some additional parameters that you should pass to get the same behavior as direct invcation in prompt. Here is an example if(!(get-command node -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)){'node not found' | Write-Error }

Comment: If you want the Unix-style behavior of giving you the path you'll need to pipe the output of get-command to `select -expandproperty Path`.

Comment: @Eld's solution is more true in spirit

Comment: As [Jason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1318689/jason-newton) suggests, the `which()` function defined by [Eld](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246826/eld)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16949127/2809027) is substantially superior to _anything_ on offer here. If it's not the equivalent of Unix `which`, it's not the right answer.

Comment: Use `(gcm <command>).definition` to get the path(s) only. `gcm` is the default alias for `Get-Command`. You can also use wildcards, eg: `(gcm win*.exe).definition`.

Comment: I'm learning ps at the moment and it seems to me that apart from maybe being a decent scripting language, it's pretty stupid for use on the command-line.

Comment: Just in case anyone else is wondering, if you peek in the Automation DLL, Source returns Definition and Definition returns Path, so these three properties will always be equivalent (barring some future change on MS's part of course);

Comment: for absolute beginners: in order for this to work copy-paste the second command in the answer in your PowerShell terminal and run it and then copy-paste & run the first one

Answer (score 203):

Here is an actual *nix equivalent, i.e. it gives *nix-style output.

```
Get-Command <your command> | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Definition
```

Just replace  with whatever you're looking for.

```
PS C:\> Get-Command notepad.exe | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Definition
C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe
```

When you add it to your profile, you will want to use a function rather than an alias because you can't use aliases with pipes:

```
function which($name)
{
    Get-Command $name | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Definition
}
```

Now, when you reload your profile you can do this:

```
PS C:\> which notepad
C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe
```

Comment: I use this alternate syntax: "(Get-Command notepad).definition"

Comment: @B00merang Your syntax is great--definitely more concise--but unfortunately, even with the pipe removed, it can't be added as an alias unless you include the name of the program you are looking for.

Comment: This is an old post, but in case anyone is sent here by Google (like I was), this answer works with more types of Powershell commands than the accepted answer. For example, I have an alias named `okta` that points to a Powershell script named `okta.ps1` that is not on my `$PATH`. Using the accepted answer returns the script name (`okta -> okta.ps1`). This is OK but it doesn't tell me the location of `okta.ps1`. 

Using this answer, however, gives me the whole path (`C:\Users\blah\etc\scripts\okta.ps1`). So +1 from me.

Answer (score 117):

I usually just type:

```
gcm notepad
```

or

```
gcm note*
```

gcm is the default alias for Get-Command.

On my system, gcm note* outputs:

```
[27] » gcm note*

CommandType     Name                                                     Definition
-----------     ----                                                     ----------
Application     notepad.exe                                              C:\WINDOWS\notepad.exe
Application     notepad.exe                                              C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe
Application     Notepad2.exe                                             C:\Utils\Notepad2.exe
Application     Notepad2.ini                                             C:\Utils\Notepad2.ini
```

You get the directory and the command that matches what you're looking for.

Comment: its a bit messy, but way cleaner than custom functions and arbitrary splits

Comment: When I type "gcm notepad" in my powershell command prompt, I just get the first two columns, and a third column called 'ModuleName' which is empty. Do you know how to force it to list the 'Definition' column by default?

Comment: @PiyushSoni that's probably because of an updated version of PowerShell. You can always display the other columns by doing something like `gcm note* | select CommandType, Name, Definition`. If you run it often, you should probably wrap it in a function, though.

Answer (score 45):

**Try this example:**

```
(Get-Command notepad.exe).Path
```

Comment: Please add more code or explanation so that the OP can understand you better. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for adding less code so I can actually remember this for once :P

Comment: This is what I wanted! It works with gcm as well: `(gcm py.exe).path`

Answer (score 12):

My proposition for the Which function:

```
function which($cmd) { get-command $cmd | % { $_.Path } }

PS C:\> which devcon

C:\local\code\bin\devcon.exe
```

Comment: This is a better answer than the accepted one.  It allows you to add the postprocessing suffixes suggested above to provide better output; an alias doesn't.

Answer (score 10):

A quick-and-dirty match to Unix `which` is

```
New-Alias which where.exe
```

But it returns multiple lines if they exist so then it becomes

```
function which {where.exe command | select -first 1}
```

Comment: `where.exe where` should tell you `C:\Windows\System32\where.exe`

Comment: `where.exe` is equivalent to `which -a`, as it will give back *all* matching executables, not just the first one to be executed. That is, `where.exe notepad` gives `c:\windows\notepad.exe` and `c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe`. So this is particularly *not* suitable for the form `$(which command)`. (Another problem is that it will print a nice, helpful error message if the command is not found, which will also not expand nicely in `$()` -- that can be remedied with `/Q`, but not as an alias.)

Comment: point taken. I edited answer but yes it's no longer so neat a solution

Comment: Please note that `where` seems to search the system PATH variable and not the current shell PATH variable. See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1544311/does-the-where-utility-of-windows-search-only-the-system-path-not-the-current-t)

Comment: `function which {where.exe $args[0] | select -first 1}` would make it reusable. Also, posh seems way more reliable in dealing with paths, quotes, and whitespaces, so `function which {$(gcm $args[0]).source | select -first 1}` might be a better choice.

Comment: also note `where` is an alias of `Where-Object` as `gcm where*` will tell you. You have to include the `.exe` to restricted it to `where.exe`. (FYI `sc.exe` is another one.) A frequent suggestion is always use the `.exe` as habit to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 7):

I like `Get-Command | Format-List`, or shorter, using aliases for the two and only for `powershell.exe`:

```
gcm powershell | fl
```

You can find aliases like this:

```
alias -definition Format-List
```

Tab completion works with `gcm`.

To have tab list all options at once:

```
set-psreadlineoption -editmode emacs
```

Answer (score 3):

This seems to do what you want (I found it on http://huddledmasses.org/powershell-find-path/):

```
Function Find-Path($Path, [switch]$All = $false, [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestPathType]$type = "Any")
## You could comment out the function stuff and use it as a script instead, with this line:
#param($Path, [switch]$All = $false, [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestPathType]$type = "Any")
   if($(Test-Path $Path -Type $type)) {
      return $path
   } else {
      [string[]]$paths = @($pwd);
      $paths += "$pwd;$env:path".split(";")

      $paths = Join-Path $paths $(Split-Path $Path -leaf) | ? { Test-Path $_ -Type $type }
      if($paths.Length -gt 0) {
         if($All) {
            return $paths;
         } else {
            return $paths[0]
         }
      }
   }
   throw "Couldn't find a matching path of type $type"
}
Set-Alias find Find-Path
```

Comment: But it's not really "which" since it works with any file(type) and doesn't find cmdlets, functions or aliases

Answer (score 3):

Check this [PowerShell Which](http://blog.stangroome.com/2007/09/06/my-manwich-powershell-which).

The code provided there suggests this:

```c
($Env:Path).Split(";") | Get-ChildItem -filter notepad.exe
```

Comment: I know it's years on, but my path had "%systemroot%\system32\..." and PowerShell doesn't expand that environment variable and throws errors doing this.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [`where`](http://ss64.com/nt/where.html) command on Windows 2003 or later (or Windows 2000/XP if you've installed a Resource Kit).

BTW, this received more answers in other questions:

[Is there an equivalent of 'which' on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/is-there-an-equivalent-of-which-on-windows)

[PowerShell equivalent to Unix `which` command?](https://superuser.com/questions/34492/powershell-equivalent-to-unix-which-command)

Comment: `where` aliases to the `Where-Object` commandlet in Powershell, so typing `where <item>` in a Powershell prompt yields nothing. This answer is thus completely incorrect - as noted in the accepted answer in the first linked question, to get the DOS `where`, you need to type `where.exe <item>`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a comamnd that both accepts input from pipeline or as paramater, you should try this:

```bsh
function which($name) {
    if ($name) { $input = $name }
    Get-Command $input | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path
}
```

copy-paste the command to your profile (`notepad $profile`).

Examples:

```bsh
❯ echo clang.exe | which
C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang.exe

❯ which clang.exe
C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

I have this `which` advanced function in my PowerShell profile:

```
    function which {
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
    Identifies the source of a PowerShell command.
    .DESCRIPTION
    Identifies the source of a PowerShell command. External commands (Applications) are identified by the path to the executable
    (which must be in the system PATH); cmdlets and functions are identified as such and the name of the module they are defined in
    provided; aliases are expanded and the source of the alias definition is returned.
    .INPUTS
    No inputs; you cannot pipe data to this function.
    .OUTPUTS
    .PARAMETER Name
    The name of the command to be identified.
    .EXAMPLE
    PS C:\Users\Smith\Documents> which Get-Command
    
    Get-Command: Cmdlet in module Microsoft.PowerShell.Core
    
    (Identifies type and source of command)
    .EXAMPLE
    PS C:\Users\Smith\Documents> which notepad
    
    C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\notepad.exe
    
    (Indicates the full path of the executable)
    #>
        param(
        [String]$name
        )
    
        $cmd = Get-Command $name
        $redirect = $null
        switch ($cmd.CommandType) {
            "Alias"          { "{0}: Alias for ({1})" -f $cmd.Name, (. { which $cmd.Definition } ) }
            "Application"    { $cmd.Source }
            "Cmdlet"         { "{0}: {1} {2}" -f $cmd.Name, $cmd.CommandType, (. { if ($cmd.Source.Length) { "in module {0}" -f $cmd.Source} else { "from unspecified source" } } ) }
            "Function"       { "{0}: {1} {2}" -f $cmd.Name, $cmd.CommandType, (. { if ($cmd.Source.Length) { "in module {0}" -f $cmd.Source} else { "from unspecified source" } } ) }
            "Workflow"       { "{0}: {1} {2}" -f $cmd.Name, $cmd.CommandType, (. { if ($cmd.Source.Length) { "in module {0}" -f $cmd.Source} else { "from unspecified source" } } ) }
            "ExternalScript" { $cmd.Source }
            default          { $cmd }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
function Which([string] $cmd) {
  $path = (($Env:Path).Split(";") | Select -uniq | Where { $_.Length } | Where { Test-Path $_ } | Get-ChildItem -filter $cmd).FullName
  if ($path) { $path.ToString() }
}

# Check if Chocolatey is installed
if (Which('cinst.bat')) {
  Write-Host "yes"
} else {
  Write-Host "no"
}
```

Or this version, calling the original where command.

This version also works better, because it is not limited to bat files:

```
function which([string] $cmd) {
  $where = iex $(Join-Path $env:SystemRoot "System32\where.exe $cmd 2>&1")
  $first = $($where -split '[\r\n]')
  if ($first.getType().BaseType.Name -eq 'Array') {
    $first = $first[0]
  }
  if (Test-Path $first) {
    $first
  }
}

# Check if Curl is installed
if (which('curl')) {
  echo 'yes'
} else {
  echo 'no'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install the `which` command from https://goprogram.co.uk/software/commands, along with all of the other UNIX commands.

Answer (score 0):

If you have [scoop](https://github.com/ScoopInstaller/Scoop) you can install a direct clone of which:

```
scoop install which
which notepad
```

Answer (score 0):

There also always the option of using which. there are actually three ways to access which from Windows powershell, the first (not necessarily the best) wsl -e which command (this requires installation of windows subsystem for Linux and a running distro). B. [gnuwin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html) which is a port of several gnu binaries in .exe format as standle alone bundled lanunchers option three, install [msys2](https://www.msys2.org/) (cross compiler platform) if you go where it installed in /usr/bin you'll find many many gnu utils that are more up-to-date. most of them work as stand alone exe and can be copied from the bin folder to your home drive somewhere amd added to your PATH.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to wrap `where.exe` into the function so that it takes binary as command line argument and put the function into `$PROFILE`. Also, to find the directory where the binary is located, it's better to use `where.exe` over `(Get-Command $binary).Source` method.

Why? Let's consider `(Get-Command $binary).Source` where `$binary` matches an alias already written in `$PROFILE` like, say, `New-Alias curl C:\curl-7.81.0-win64-mingw\bin\curl.exe` (because you want to use the curl installed by yourself, not the one in system32). Then the `(Get-Command curl).Source` will output nothing. Moreover, even `(Get-Command curl.exe).Source` will only output the path to system32:

```
C:\Windows\System32\curl.exe
```

when `where.exe curl` output looks like this:

```
C:\Windows\System32\curl.exe
C:\curl-7.81.0-win64-mingw\bin\curl.exe
```

The same is for default PowerShell aliases, such as `where`. The expected output of `(Get-Command where).Source` or `(Get-Command where).Definition` would be `C:\Windows\System32\where.exe` but it just returns nothing instead and `"Where-Object"` respectively.

So, the code to add into the `$PROFILE`:

```
function Find-Binary($binary) {
    $location = where.exe $binary 2>$null
    Write-Output $location
}

New-Alias wi Find-Binary
```

`wi` is short for `whereis`

Then use it like this:

```
wi your_binary
```

or

```
Find-Binary your_binary
```

Answer (score -1):

There also always the option of using which. there are actually three ways to access which from Windows powershell

- The first, (though not the best) is wsl(windows subsystem for linux)

```sh
wsl -e which command
```

This requires installation of windows subsystem for Linux and a running distro.

- Next is [gnuwin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html) which is a port of several gnu binaries in .exe format as standle alone bundled lanunchers
- Third, install [msys2](https://www.msys2.org/) (cross compiler platform) if you go where it installed in /usr/bin you'll find many many gnu utils that are more up-to-date. most of them work as stand alone exe and can be copied from the bin folder to your home drive somewhere amd added to your PATH.