# how to launch a .exe using window registry in java

Tags: java, python, windows, winapi

My application is written in python,but it's gui is built in java(swing).so,i need to launch python.exe through java.so,i need to get the path of python.exe dynamically(path must not be hard coded)
runtime.exec() wont work here,as it needs hardcoded path of exe file.
even System.getenv() because python doesnt set environment variable automatically.
I have some hope with Window registry.
Please help.

Comment: for reading stuff from the windows registry from java, see [this question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java

Comment: i have gone through the question,but didnt get my answer.

Comment: public static String readString(int hkey, String key, String valueName)                                                                   what is hkey,key valueName??                                              what should be values of these variables for python.exe???

Answer (score 0):

1. How you get the Python path is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647515/how-can-i-know-pythons-path-under-windows). All you have to know is the version you want. Or you enumerate all existing nodes.
2. Reading the registry from Java is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java) as radei wrote.

Comment: got location,but i need key as well to read registry file.how can i get it?

Comment: public static String readString(int hkey, String key, String valueName)                                                                   what is hkey,key valueName??                                              what should be values of these variables for python.exe???

Comment: It is all mentioned in the links I gave you.
  1. The key is HKEY_CURRENT_USER or HKEYL_LOCAL_MACHINE 
  2. I.e. for Version 2.6 the Path is \Software\Python\Pythoncore\2.6\InstallPath 
  3. the valuName is empty.<br/> Expolore the registry by your own, You have all information you nee. Use Google!