# Locate Python binary location in windows (Tensorflow)

Tags: python, r, tensorflow

I'm trying to follow tensorflow instructions in R but am stuck on providing the Python binary path location on Windows. I believe the instructions are given to Mac environment? I would like to know where can I locate my Python binary on my windows environment.

Link to Tutorial: https://github.com/rstudio/tensorflow

```
Sys.setenv(TENSORFLOW_PYTHON="/usr/local/bin/python")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I know python's path under windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647515/how-can-i-know-pythons-path-under-windows)

Answer (score 1):

Try this on the command prompt:

```
python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"
```

That will give you the full executable path for the python version that you are using.

**Output: [Your output may be different]**

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe
```