# How do I uninstall Python 2.5.4 x86 on Win 7?

Tags: python

I've got the problem with Python 2.5.4 x86 on Win 7.

Unfortunately, my installer doesn't offer uninstallation.

I played around with installing many python version, but I finally need only 3.X and "magically" there is this Python 2.5.4.

What can I do?

Comment: Try Revo Uninstaller?

Comment: I try to avoid installing excess programs. I used GeekUninstaller (which is portable) and there I can see only Python 3.X. This version I need.

Comment: Do you need to uninstall it, or do you just need a different version to be available for use on that machine? Those are not the same thing.

Comment: Well... I need 3.6 to open some script. Earlier versions can stay.

Comment: maybe check the location where Python *is* installed and being used (this answer should help get that: [How can I get Python path under Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/647798/1248974)), then navigate to that location and see if there is an "uninstall" executable. Also, inspecting the installed programs in "Control Panel" might be helpful.

Comment: If there is no uninstallation option, then you can find that versions installer, reinstall it, then perform an uninstallation

Comment: @cricket_007 Like Saint Thomas... https://vgy.me/UWil4G.png

Answer (score 1):

You start by running the installer for the python that you want to remove (python 2.5.4)
Then, you click remove python 2.5.4 and click finished
Next, go to Windows Control Panel and click Programs and Features
After that, find python 2.5.4 and uninstall it

[wikihow.com/Uninstall-Python](https://www.wikihow.com/Uninstall-Python)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Comment: i am sorry, but it helpfull

Comment: The content of your answer should then cover the steps **and** provide the link. You are welcome to edit to update it

Comment: I Fixed it to your standards

Comment: I want to point that in Python 2.5.4 installer there is **no** uninstaller option. 

This Python mess is probably created or/and augumented by the fact that installed Anki (which uses Python 2.5) and AmeSIM (which uses Python 2.7).

On top of that, today I installed Python 3.X.

I need only Python 3.X. What should I do?

Comment: 2.5 and 2.7 were installed by other programs in the past.

I also installed 2.5, 3.5, 3.7 manually recently.

Comment: can you specify?

Comment: What do you mean? What kind of data should I provide?

Comment: some screenshots may be helpful

Comment: Can you recommend what I should type in cmd?

I'm fighting with this:
https://www.reddit.com/r/Xiaomi/comments/7r2ed5/yeelight_app_alternative/dstq4b8/

To be more precise:
https://nofile.io/f/v3ZyK3j9Wtp/fluxee-master.zip

This doesn't work with Python 2.X.

Comment: @Hippolippo just check my comment before yours

Comment: If the reason that you want to uninstall the old version is because the code doesn't work in it, then run it with the new version, if you do not no how I can post another answer that shows how.

Comment: I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.