# Why do I have two different python directories, python36-32 and python36?

Tags: python

I am trying to install some modules within python, they either say that the module is installed in the directory: python36-32\lib\site-packages or the directory: python\python36\site-packages

Comment: Did you install python twice? Maybe python comes preinstalled on your machine. What OS is this?

Comment: @ FHTMitchell I am using windows 10, and I have only installed python once, but I have repaired it a couple times.

Comment: I'd suggest to look which python installation is in %PATH% with `path` at command prompt. I think you somehow installed or tried installing a 32bit version too. also worth a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647515/how-can-i-find-where-python-is-installed-on-windows