# OperationalError: no such module: fts4

Tags: fts4, operationalerror

Hi I´ve tried to run a fuzzymatcher code and the error below pops up:

```
OperationalError: no such module: fts4
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Edit: I've already tried downloading the sqlite zip from the website and saving it in DLLs files but it still does not work. Do I have to activate it somehow?

I´m using Anaconda3 64 bit.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Confirm that the DLL files have been added in the correct place; if you are using Windows it will be `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\DLLs`.
2. you can try to load the extensions:

```py
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
cur = conn.cursor()
conn.enable_load_extension(True)

for (val,) in cur.execute('pragma compile_options'): 
    print (val)
```

It will show some results similar to these:

```
COMPILER=msvc-1500
ENABLE_BYTECODE_VTAB
ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA
ENABLE_DBSTAT_VTAB
ENABLE_FTS3
ENABLE_FTS4
ENABLE_FTS5
ENABLE_GEOPOLY
ENABLE_JSON1
ENABLE_RTREE
ENABLE_STMTVTAB
MAX_TRIGGER_DEPTH=100
TEMP_STORE=1
THREADSAFE=1
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Ahmed and @Jeremy in the previous answer,

> Confirm that the DLL files have been added in the correct place

However, make sure that it is indeed the correct place. For example, if you're working in a virtual environment, the location **is not** `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\DLLs`.

[Check where python is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647515/how-can-i-find-where-python-is-installed-on-windows) to find the correct place.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the downloaded sqlite files in C:\Users\ (usernamefolder)\anaconda3\DLLs and check for the enabled extensions using the following syntax in jupyter notebook.

```
  import sqlite3
  conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
  cur = conn.cursor()
  conn.enable_load_extension(True)

for (val,) in cur.execute('pragma compile_options'): 
    print (val)
```

This will give the list of extensions which are enabled and FTS-4 will be one of them. In case you tried and it still hasn't been enabled you can uninstall and reinstall anaconda package and try repeating the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me

install this in anacoda prompt using the comand below

conda install -c conda-forge sqlite-fts4