# error: no such module: fts4; using - fuzzymatcher package with anaconda jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm using jupyter notebook and trying to run this code:

```
import pubchempy as pcp
from rdkit import Chem
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import json
import time
import fuzzymatcher

start_time = time.time()
#     CD = pd.read_excel(excelpathin)

    data = pd.ExcelFile(r"C:\Users\USER\Downloads\MOD_REINJ_NEG_ChemSpider Results.xlsx")
    data = pd.ExcelFile(excelpathin)

    df = data.parse (sheet_name=0)
    inKey = list()
    for idx,sd in enumerate(df['Structure']):
        print(idx)
        F = open ("temp.sdf","w")
        F.writelines (sd)
        F.close()
        suppl = Chem.SDMolSupplier ('temp.sdf')
        mol = next (suppl)
        if mol==None:
            inKey.append (np.nan)
        else:
            inKey.append (Chem.MolToInchiKey (mol))

    inKey = pd.DataFrame(inKey)
    inKey.columns = ['InChIKey']
    CD = pd.concat([df, inKey], axis=1, sort=False)
    
    
    print("--- %s seconds --f-add 3 cols" % (time.time() - start_time))

    # From here is the joindata function with modification
    # Load the parse HMDB file
    with open(jsonpathin, 'r') as read_file:
        data = json.load(read_file)

    start_time = time.time()
    # Load the parse HMDB file
    # with open('D:/BCDD/Documents/Tal/Projects/HMDB/DataSets/Parser_HMDB.py Output/serum_metabolites.json', 'r') as read_file:
    #     data = json.load(read_file)


    # Create a data frame from the list of dictionaries
    # df_hmdb = pd.DataFrame(data,  columns=['accession', 'name', 'chemical_formula', 'inchikey', 'disease_name' ])
    df_hmdb = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df_hmdb.drop(['description', 'synonyms', 'kegg_id', 'meta_cyc_id', 'pathway_name'], axis=1)

    df_excel = CD
    # Merge by inchikey
    joindata_by_inchikey = pd.merge(left=df_excel, right=df_hmdb, how='inner', left_on='InChIKey', right_on='inchikey')

    print("--- %s seconds --f-merge by inchikey " % (time.time() - start_time))

    start_time = time.time()
    # Reduce the rows to those we DID find a match by inchkey in bothe data sets
    df_hmdb_reduce_byinchik = df_hmdb.loc[~df_hmdb['inchikey'].isin(df_excel['InChIKey'])]
    df_excel_reduce_byinchik = df_excel.loc[~df_excel['InChIKey'].isin(joindata_by_inchikey['InChIKey'])]


    # joindata_by_name = fuzzymatcher.fuzzy_left_join(df_excel, df_hmdb, left_on="Name", right_on="name")
    joindata_by_name = fuzzymatcher.fuzzy_left_join(df_excel_reduce_byinchik, df_hmdb_reduce_byinchik, left_on="Name",
                                                    right_on="name")

    # Selecting threshold  best_match_score>0.25 maybe adjustments needed
    joindata_by_name = joindata_by_name[joindata_by_name['best_match_score'] > 0.55]
    # Drop columns the
    joindata_by_name.drop(['best_match_score', '__id_left', '__id_right'], axis=1, inplace=True)
    print("--- %s seconds --f-merge by name" % (time.time() - start_time))

    start_time = time.time()
    # Reduce the rows to those we DID find a match by inchkey in and by name both data sets
    df_hmdb_reduce_byname = df_hmdb_reduce_byinchik.loc[~df_hmdb_reduce_byinchik['name'].isin(joindata_by_name['name'])]
    df_excel_reduce_byname = df_excel_reduce_byinchik.loc[
        ~df_excel_reduce_byinchik['Name'].isin(joindata_by_name['Name'])]
    # Remove spaces between letters on  'Formula' ( there is  a warning)
    df_excel_reduce_byname.loc[:, 'Formula'] = df_excel_reduce_byname['Formula'].str.replace(' ', '')

    # Merge by chemical_formula
    joindata_by_CF = pd.merge(left=df_excel_reduce_byname, right=df_hmdb_reduce_byname, how='inner', left_on='Formula',
                              right_on='chemical_formula')

    # This data inculed rows from the original EXCEL file that we did NOT find and match ( by inchikey nor name nor CF)
    df_excel_reduce_byCF = df_excel_reduce_byname.loc[
        ~df_excel_reduce_byname['Formula'].isin(joindata_by_CF['chemical_formula'])]

    # Create a list of all columns of the HMDB JSON data
    colnames = joindata_by_inchikey.columns[6:]
    # Add those names as empty columns to the df_excel_reduce_byCF. reducedata in all the rows from the original Excel
    # that did NOT find a match and added the columns of the HMDB
    reducedata = df_excel_reduce_byCF.reindex(columns=[*df_excel_reduce_byCF.columns.tolist(), *colnames])

    # Append all the data sets
    # out = joindata_by_inchikey.append(joindata_by_name.append(joindata_by_CF))
    out = joindata_by_inchikey.append(joindata_by_name.append(joindata_by_CF.append(reducedata)))

    print("--- %s seconds --f-merge by CF" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

(I'm not sure the code is relevant since I load files that are not shared in quesion)

This is the error I get:

```
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-26c4a723b687> in <module>
     23 # joindata_by_name = fuzzymatcher.fuzzy_left_join(df_excel, df_hmdb, left_on="Name", right_on="name")
     24 joindata_by_name = fuzzymatcher.fuzzy_left_join(df_excel_reduce_byinchik, df_hmdb_reduce_byinchik, left_on="Name",
---> 25                                                 right_on="name")
     26 
     27 # Selecting threshold  best_match_score>0.25 maybe adjustments needed

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fuzzymatcher\__init__.py in fuzzy_left_join(df_left, df_right, left_on, right_on, left_id_col, right_id_col)
     39     m = Matcher(dp, dg, s)
     40     m.add_data(df_left, df_right, left_on, right_on,  left_id_col, right_id_col)
---> 41     m.match_all()
     42 
     43     return m.get_left_join_table()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fuzzymatcher\matcher.py in match_all(self)
     87         self.scorer.add_data(self)
     88 
---> 89         self.data_getter.add_data(self)
     90 
     91         # Get a table that contains only the matches, scores and ids

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fuzzymatcher\data_getter_sqlite.py in add_data(self, matcher)
     58                  USING fts4({} TEXT, _concat_all TEXT, _concat_all_alternatives TEXT);
     59               """.format(matcher.right_id_col)
---> 60         con.execute(sql)
     61         con.execute("INSERT INTO fts_target SELECT * FROM df_right_processed")
     62 

OperationalError: no such module: fts4
```

The line with error of fuzzymatcher **used** to **work** using Pycharme on different computer but on jupyter notebook it does not.

I checked this for answers :

1. [perationalError: No Such Module:fts4](https://github.com/RobinL/fuzzymatcher/issues/44)
2. [OperationalError: no such module: fts4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61901689/operationalerror-no-such-module-fts4)

But no use and I do not understand what to do

any help idea hint thoughts are fappreciated

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you describe and I found the solution.

1. You have to go to https://www.sqlite.org/download.html and Download appropriate dll files from Precompiled Binaries for Windows section of this page. You must download either 32bit or 64bit according to your hardware architecture.
2. Extract the zip file and copy the content and paste and then manually pasted it into "your python \bin folder".

After (1) and (2) I could use fuzzymatcher package without problems in Jupyter Notebook.

If these steps do not resolve your questions you will see the following website: https://deshmukhsuraj.wordpress.com/2015/02/07/windows-python-users-update-your-sqlite3/comment-page-1/?unapproved=947&moderation-hash=9de09b93a31bd079256474474e71b32d#comment-947

Looking that website was so useful for me to find the answer for the problem.
I hope it will useful for you.
Best