# Trying to find location of python scripts file to add as variable value to PATH variable

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Hi im trying to convert my python file into an exe. With the guide im following, i have to find the location of python scripts file. This apparently so i can install pyinstaller to turn my .py in an exe.

How would i find the location of python scripts file?

I’m on python 3 on windows

Comment: Are you on windows/linux/mac? Python 2.7 or 3?

Comment: @CarloZanocco python 3 on windows

Comment: There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647515/how-can-i-find-where-python-is-installed-on-windows)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you use auto-py-to-exe instead, to install this type:

```
pip3 install auto-py-to-exe
```

Next just type:

```
auto-py-to-exe
```

Into the terminal and it will be pretty straightforward from then on.

Answer (score 1):

On the cmd line (or terminal) type

```
where python
```

or run this in a script:

```
import sys
import os
print(os.path.dirname)
print(os.path.dirname(sys.executable))
```