# Why can't Python find the module I installed?

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, conda, modulenotfounderror

Presently I'm using Python on a Windows system. I installed Python 3.10 from Anaconda and also the Pycharm IDE. I have ensured that Python is in the correct path in the environment variable. I have also replicated this problem using two different versions of Python, 3.10 and 3.9.

Very simply, in PyCharm, I open a terminal and type

```
conda install -c numpy numpy.
```

Then, I write a new "main.py" script. I have one line: "import numpy". I receive the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\---\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\main.py", line 17, in <module>
    import numpy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Going on advice from a friend, I created a new PyCharm project sitting not in my user directory but on the C: drive, and got the same error. Finally, when trying to re-install the package using either using either pip or conda, I get this message:

```
# All requested packages already installed.
```

Comment: Can you show how you invoke your script? Do you get the same problem on the interactive Python prompt?

Comment: E.g., if you're calling your script via `python3 main.py` but conda only installed the name `python` (which is the default), you could be getting the wrong instance of python.

Comment: I'm literally just running it in Pycharm. So I don't type "python3 main.py", I just hit the green play button and I get this error. Worth mentioning that when I hit "conda list" or "pip list," it shows that I have numpy installed.

Comment: So, now I really want to troubleshoot, does Pycharm see the same environment as you get on the command line. Run a script containing just `import os` and then `print(os.__file__)`. Do you get the same answer in both cases? What I get is `path_to_my_current_venv/lib/os.py` so if the result is different, that would be your problem. I'm going at the same thing as @Giorgios's answer, actually.

Comment: No, these are different lines. The first gives me "C:/Users/.../PycharmProjects/pythonProject5/main.py" and the second gives me "C:\Users\...\anaconda3\envs\pythonProject5\lib\os.py". What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Then the answers below are correct: you have PyCharm misconfigured and using the wrong environment. I believe the answer from @Giorgos is telling you want to do, but I have never use PyCharm so I cannot help you past this point. Comment under their answer if you don't understand their solution, they might be able to clarify it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 versions of Python:

1. Default Python (used everytime you open your command prompt and type `python` or `python3`)
2. Anaconda is installing packages in a virtual environment, using it's own Python (it is located in a different path)

You can see the path of your installed python using `python -c "import os, sys; print(os.path.dirname(sys.executable))"`

You have 2 Options:

1. Configure the PyCharm in order to use the anaconda Python. [https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#view_list](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html)
2. Open a command prompt in the project's folder (you can do it easily using PyCharm). Type `conda env list`. This will show you all available anaconda virtual environments. Choose 1 of them and type `conda activate <env_name>`, where <env_name>=the name of the environment. Then, run your program using `python <name_of_your_program>`

You can see the paths where the anaconda environments and packages are installed using `conda info`

Comment: Thank you. I opted to change the environment using PyCharm.

Answer (score 1):

There main reason for this is

> You are running your `main.py` in different environment rather than where you installed numpy.

**If you trying to run it via cmd use this method**

> Check which environment you are in right now. refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589711/find-full-path-of-the-python-interpreter) and
> [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647515/how-can-i-find-where-python-is-installed-on-windows). But the most easiest way to do this is use `where` command
> in windows cmd. `C:\> where python` or `C:\> where python3`. You will
> get the path of activated interpreter.
>
> list conda envs - `conda env list`
>
> activate conda env - `conda activate <env name>`
>
> then run this command. `pip freeze` . and check is there `numpy` in
> the list. If not you have to find and activate the environment where
> you have installed numpy.

**If you want to run it in pycharm**

> Refer this on how to change pycharm interpreter.
> https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html

Answer (score 0):

Many things can cause this, usually its one of these

1. You may have to restart your terminal, or IDE if running in there, after installing a package to "refresh" the environmental path
2. The package is not in the environmental path

Comment: So I've restarted PyCharm and Anaconda several times. I've made sure that the environment path variables include a path to the version of Python I am using. I have made sure that the package is installed in the environment (eg, I have typed "conda list" or "pip list," the package shows up.