How to run .py script from anywhere in command line (windows)
I know this has been asked plenty of times but I haven't found a satisfactory answer to my particular question (maybe it's out there but I didn't check every single related thread).
Simply put, I want to able to run a .py script from anywhere in command line WITHOUT having to go to the folder where it's located. Is this possible? Despite having both python as well as the folder containing my scripts being in the PATH environment variable, I always get the message

"python: can't open file 'C:\Users\dpodo\Runtime.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

From what I've found so far, Windows can't explicitly run python scripts from anywhere, it can only do this with executable files, but I refer to you guys to help me out here.
As above, already tried adding python and the script folder to PATH, and Googling a bit, as well as checking a few threads here on SO.

just adding to PATH should work. It works for me. What's the contents of your python files?

Don't remember the exact details, but it should be possible to configure .py to be recognized as an executable file extension. It should also be possible to figure python.exe to be used to run .py files. Then you just need the .py files to be in path and it should then work.

@Jean-FrançoisFabre Nothing special, just some basic functions I want to test, so it should print out a few things before quitting only once I allow it to.

For specific python files from projects that have a virtual environment (which should be all of them, at this point) that you want to invoke anywhere, any time, you can create a .bat file that runs the python from your virtual environment (full path), with the full path for your script as argument. Then just have that .bat file live in a dir that's in your PATH (so you generally want a dedicated folder for that so you can put as many .bat files in there as you need to run distinct, known, python scripts)
For example, if you have a D:\Temp\test.py and your virtual environment lives in D:\Temp\venv, then you create a .bat file containing:
D:\Temp\venv\Scripts\python.exe D:\Temp\test.py`

And you just make sure that your user's PATH includes the folder that .bat file lives in.
If, however, you want to be able to execute arbitrary python scripts by just double-clicking them, or typing the (full path) name in ps/cmd, then you need to hit up Settings, get to Choose default apps by file types, find the .py extension, and then tell Windows to use Python, rather than whatever code editor is presumably currently set to open those files when you double-click/run them.
Done, any .py file you run without explicitly invokine it as argument to a python interpreter will now run with whatever Windows thinks "pyhon" is. Which you can find out using the instructions mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/647798/740553
Which might not be the version you want at all, which is why virtual environments are a thing =)

I can run the .py file if I enter the full path name in cmd, but I was hoping that I can be anywhere in cmd and run it regardless. I.e. Say the script is saved in "C:\MyDocuments\Python\Scripts[myscript.py]", I could obviously just go to this folder in CMD and then enter "python myscript.py", this works.
I was hoping that I can be anywhere else, i.e. C:\users\me\ and still enter the above command without having to navigate to the specific folder.

You're still bound to the rules of the OS: only executables (or files that the OS knows how to execute by invoking another program) located in folders that are in PATH work that way, and it checks those paths in order. Otherwise how would your OS know which "run.py" you mean, from the million potential run.py you might have scattered everywhere?

I would have thought that since I've put in the folder (where the py script is) into PATH, Windows will only check if "run.py" exists within that folder and nowhere else, hence limiting the number of other possible files named the same way (and I also name my py scripts in a very specific manner to avoid such naming conflicts anyway).

You don't control the content for every other folder in the PATH, so simply assuming that your own run.py is the only script by that name that can be found in any folder in your path would, at best, be "only true for now". That's not something you want to rely on. However, another option not covered here is to compile your script to a real executable instead by using pyinstaller. Then you can just give it a real name (not "run") and run it without having to do any .py extension binding.

Solution for Windows and Linux
So you would need python installed and added to path (Which it does by default so no need to worry). Then you would need to take the directory where your .py file is and add it to the path (Make sure to add the dir/folder where the file is not the file itself).
Windows Solution
For windows it pretty simple, look for a application called Edit the system environment variables, open it and double click the text that says path. then press new and add the path of the parent dir of the file.
Linux Solution
For Linux its also pretty simple, all you need to do is open your terminal and run the following command nano .bashrc then go to the bottom of the file and paste the following export PATH="/Directory1:$PATH" and replace Directory1 with the dir you need.
Final Steps (For all Operating systems)
Now just run python your_file_name.py or python3 your_file_name.py and replace your_file_name with the name of the file that you are running.

Already did that, before coming to this forum, and it doesn't work.

You might want to wait for other answers or look on other articles or posts. I had no problem running scripts I just changed smth but I don't remember what.
