# How to find where Apache's httpd.exe is installed?

Tags: windows, apache

How do I best figure out if and where Apache is installed on a windows machine?

I'm writing a script that uses the installed apache, but sets up it's own config & server-root, and I don't want to hardcode it nor have the user explicitly set it (unless necessary).

I tried to search the registry, but couldn't find anything useful.

**Update for those posting default paths**

On my machine, it was in C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2. And if I had Vista 64-bit, it'd probably be under 'Program Files (x86)'. And if the computer doesn't have an English OS, it's even worse.

**Workaround**

Guess I have to check %PROGRAMFILES% for Apache 2.0 or 2.2's default path, then fall back to a prompt. It's be nice to read the registry and find out exactly where it is.

**Final note**

Apache was not installed for 'Everyone', but only the current user. That makes it a bit more difficult to find as there are no services nor registry keys/folders to point there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/is-there-an-equivalent-of-which-on-windows

Comment: Works if httpd.exe is in the path, but I'm not sure it is? (Will check tomorrow)

Comment: It's not in the path, so this won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apparently installed Apache only for me (current user), not for all users on my machine, hence no registry key.

If installed for all users, the registry key is here:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Apache Software Foundation\Apache\2.2.xx\ServerRoot
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the path to the service exe in the services.msc too.

(my apache for some reason is installed in AppData. don't know why if it's because I've installed using chocolatey)

[image]

then

[image]

then

[image]

PS: sorry, about the portuguese in the UI. but I guess it still pretty understandable.

--

***EDIT***

programaticaly you may run this line in cmd and check if it helps: `wmic service get PathName | findstr apache`

Comment: How to find that programmatically though? I needed it from python or from an installer IIRC.

Comment: run this line in cmd and check if it helps: `wmic service get PathName | findstr apache`

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but if I were you, I'd only use the default path (%PROGRAMFILES%\Apache Group\Apache2\bin\Apache.exe) or a couple of relatively safe default paths, and prompt if the executable was not found.

Otherwise it might pick up a completely unexpected installation. I hate programs that are "too smart".

Comment: Seems like this is the only way. The registry key in the doc does not contain the default ServerRoot as stated. :-|

Comment: Not sufficient, see my own answer here to the proper solution. Finding something _and_ prompting anyway is a good idea though, if it comes to that. (This installer was pretty limited in scope anyway...)

Answer (score 1):

Search for httpd.exe in the registry under HKLM\Services\CurrentControlSet.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows it is installed in c:/Program Files/Apache Group/Apache2/bin/Apache.exe

Rest of the directories (conf, log, doc-root, etc) are under c:/Program Files/Apache Group/Apache2

Comment: yeah, if you follow the Qick Installation route when installing Apache, this is where it'd go by default. but I think this isn't a solution to marc's problem.

Comment: Precisely, It doesn't end up there always, only by default. In my case, I had forgotten to install it for All Users.