# How to locate fuslogvw.exe on my machine?

Tags: .net

I'm looking for the assembly binding log viewer executable (fuslogvw.exe), but I can't seem to find it on my machine. It's there for sure because when I type fuslogvw in a Visual Studio command prompt the application opens.

The machine I'm working on has a clean Visual Studio 2008 installation, no previous versions were ever installed.

Does anyone know where to find it? I need the exe to be able to copy it to a server to solve a binding issue.

Comment: that's exactly where Everything(http://www.voidtools.com/Everything-1.2.1.371.exe) comes in super-handy :)

Comment: or the built-in command `where` (`>where cmd` -> `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`), although that only works if it's already discoverable in your path

Answer (score 125, accepted):

On my box, also with VS2008, it can be found at

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\fuslogvw.exe

In Windows 7, and Windows 8.1, it's located under the directories that are here:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows{version}\bin{.NET Version Tools}

So for Windows 8.1 and .NET 4.5.1:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1a\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\

Comment: On Windows 7 Pack 1 found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools

Comment: Windows 10 with .Net 4.7.1:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7.1 Tools

Answer (score 13):

My Computer has it in a different place under Tools for Visual Studio 2010

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0
>   Tools\x64\

Open the folder and run FUSLOGVW.exe as administrator then you can enable the log in settings.

Comment: +1 specially for 'run FUSLOGVW.exe as administrator'.

Answer (score 7):

Might be late to the party but maybe some of you might be interested in a modern alternative to FUSLOGVW.exe I put on GitHub: [Fusion++](https://github.com/awaescher/Fusion)

[image: Fusion++]

It's super easy to use: Just click "Record" to capture assembly logs. If you are done, click "Stop" again and Fusion++ will parse all the log files for you.

Answer (score 5):

Use the Visual Studio / development tools command prompt.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx

> This tool is automatically installed with Visual Studio. To run the
>   tool, use the Developer Command Prompt (or the Visual Studio Command
>   Prompt in Windows 7) with administrator credentials. For more
>   information, see Visual Studio Command Prompt.
>
> At the command prompt, type the following:
>
> fuslogvw

Answer (score 4):

On my machine it's in the SDK's `bin` directory.

To help you out, here's a quick-n-dirty batch file nightmare that will search the path for a file you give it:

```
@if EXIST %1 echo .\%1
@for %%e in (%PATHEXT%) do @for %%i in (%1%%e) do @if EXIST %%i echo .\%%i
@if NOT "%~$PATH:1"=="" echo %~$PATH:1
@for %%e in (%PATHEXT%) do @for %%i in (%1%%e) do @if NOT "%%~$PATH:i"=="" echo %%~$PATH:i
```

Comment: +1 for reminding me while windows batch scripts make my eyes bleed :)

Comment: To help find it from a command prompt one can do
cd\
dir /s fuslogvw.exe

Comment: What about this? 
`for %i in (cmd.exe) do @echo.   %~$PATH:i`
From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/is-there-an-equivalent-of-which-on-windows

Answer (score 3):

Windows 10:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX [INSERT VERSION HERE] Tools

Answer (score 1):

You can run this tool via Visual Studio Command Prompt (Make sure to run the command prompt as Administrator):

[image]

Note: It's also a quick way to use Registry Editor to enable assembly binding: [How to enable Assembly Binding Logging (Fusion Log Viewer – fuslogvw.exe)?](https://port135.com/2018/05/17/how-to-enable-assembly-binding-logging-debugging-net-applications/)

Answer (score 0):

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin