# why I can't find fuslogvw.exe in my c drive

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have IIS 6 installed on my front end server but I am not able to find fuslogvw.exe anywhere.

Are there any special requirements to install it?

I also found this question [Can't locate fuslogvw.exe on my machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674279/cant-locate-fuslogvw-exe-on-my-machine) but it didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fuslogvw is automatically installed with **Visual Studio** and with the **Windows SDK.**
See relevant for reference [MSDN Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx)

Mine is at `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin`

> If you have Visual Studio installed on your computer: On the taskbar,
>   click Start, click All Programs, click Visual Studio, click Visual
>   Studio Tools, right-click Visual Studio Command Prompt, and then click
>   Run as administrator from the shortcut menu.
>
> -or-
>
> If you have the Windows SDK installed on your computer: On the taskbar, click Start, click All Programs, click the folder for the
>   Windows SDK, right-click Command Prompt (or CMD Shell), and then click
>   Run as administrator from the shortcut menu. At the administrator
>   command prompt, type the following:
>   `fuslowvw`

Comment: I can't install visual studio on live server, what I do now :(

Comment: @yurikilochek perform the tests on your development box. If this you're only missing an assembly in the live version - I would investigate what is different from your development machine - such as; do you DLL missing from your installer, or a required dependency not installed on the live system.
Good luck!

Comment: There is a reason I can't test it on development server sir, i must need to figure out it on live server, thanks for your help anyway