# System.InvalidOperationException: Recurring job can't be scheduled

Tags: c#, hangfire

I have this api endpoint which run C# hangfire.

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<IIngestService>(x => x.Process("ABC"), cronExpression, TimeZoneInfo.Local);
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<IIngestService>(x => x.Process("XYZ"), cronExpression, TimeZoneInfo.Local);
```

Problem is it always run `Process("XYZ")` only. Then I figure that I have to include recurringjobid if the method name are the same.

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<IIngestService>("ABC", x => x.Process("ABC"), cronExpression, TimeZoneInfo.Local);
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<IIngestService>("XYZ", x => x.Process("XYZ"), cronExpression, TimeZoneInfo.Local);
```

When I run the job manually from HangFire web, it works without error. But, when hangfire scheduler starts the job automatically after one minute (My cron job is * * * * *), it breaks.

The error message is:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Recurring job can't be scheduled,
> see inner exception for details.  --->
> Hangfire.Common.JobLoadException: Could not load the job. See inner
> exception for the details.  ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not
> load type 'xxx.IIngestService' from assembly 'xxx.Service,
> Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.    at
> System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(QCallAssembly assembly,
> String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase,
> ObjectHandleOnStack type, ObjectHandleOnStack keepAlive,
> ObjectHandleOnStack assemblyLoadContext)

Comment: Try to use [fuslogvw.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1674318/2557855) to find out why you can't load the assembly

Comment: What is your .NET version, I tried to reproduce issue in .NET Core 3.1 and .NET 5 but it is working fine. This issue is open already with Hangfire: https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues?q=is%3Aopen+Recurring.

Comment: I'm using .Net core 3.1

Comment: Might want to show what project/packages are involved (e.g. what does your `.csproj` look like, etc.)

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Did you find a solution for it?