# JRE installation directory in Windows

Tags: java

Is there any command to check the active (since the machine can have more than 1 JRE installed) JRE installation directory under Windows. For linux, the corresponding command is

```
which java
```

Is there any Windows equivalent ?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/is-there-an-equivalent-of-which-on-the-windows-command-line

Comment: I was installing ZAP and it required the location of the JRE. So I installed it from https://adoptium.net/ and used the following command in CMD: `for %i in (java.exe) do @echo.   %~$PATH:i` and then locate from the installation window.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`where java` works for me to list all java exe but `java -verbose` tells you which `rt.jar` is used and thus which jre (full path):

```
[Opened C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\rt.jar]
...
```

Edit: win7 and java:

```
java version "1.6.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.3-b01, mixed mode)
```

Comment: where java didn't work under Windows. java -verbose did the trick as you mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: When I do java -verbose i dont get to see the path. Which version of java, Winbdows you are trying this on?

Comment: @RC: where java will only work with Win7 / Win2008 I reckon.

Comment: Using win7, where and verbose are working.

Comment: Incredible!  I didn't know that command existed on Win8, but apparently it does.  Thanks!

Answer (score 23):

Not as a command, but this information is in the registry:

- Open the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment`
- Read the `CurrentVersion` REG_SZ
- Open the subkey under `Java Runtime Environment` named with the `CurrentVersion` value
- Read the `JavaHome` REG_SZ to get the path

For example on my workstation i have

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment
  CurrentVersion = "1.6"
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\1.5
  JavaHome = "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.5.0_20"
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\1.6
  JavaHome = "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6"
```

So my current JRE is in `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6`

Comment: That is not necessarily correct, as the current path may locate a different Java executable. This just indicates the version installed with the Oracle installer.

Answer (score 8):

Following on from my other comment, here's a batch file which displays the current JRE or JDK based on the registry values.

It's different from the other solutions in instances where java is installed, but not on the `PATH`.

```
@ECHO off

SET KIT=JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment
call:ReadRegValue VER "HKLM\Software\%KIT%" "CurrentVersion"
IF "%VER%" NEQ "" GOTO FoundJRE

SET KIT=Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment
call:ReadRegValue VER "HKLM\Software\%KIT%" "CurrentVersion"
IF "%VER%" NEQ "" GOTO FoundJRE

SET KIT=JavaSoft\Java Development Kit
call:ReadRegValue VER "HKLM\Software\%KIT%" "CurrentVersion"
IF "%VER%" NEQ "" GOTO FoundJRE

SET KIT=Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit
call:ReadRegValue VER "HKLM\Software\%KIT%" "CurrentVersion"
IF "%VER%" NEQ "" GOTO FoundJRE

ECHO Failed to find Java
GOTO :EOF

:FoundJRE
call:ReadRegValue JAVAPATH "HKLM\Software\%KIT%\%VER%" "JavaHome"
ECHO %JAVAPATH%
GOTO :EOF

:ReadRegValue
SET key=%2%
SET name=%3%
SET "%~1="
SET reg=reg
IF DEFINED ProgramFiles(x86) (
  IF EXIST %WINDIR%\sysnative\reg.exe SET reg=%WINDIR%\sysnative\reg.exe
)
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=3* skip=1" %%A IN (`%reg% QUERY %key% /v %name% 2^>NUL`) DO SET "%~1=%%A %%B"
GOTO :EOF
```

Answer (score 5):

Look the answer to my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454424/unix-which-java-equivalent-command-on-windows)

```
c:\> for %i in (java.exe) do @echo.   %~$PATH:i
C:\WINDOWS\system32\java.exe
```

Answer (score -1):

In the command line you can type `java -version`

Comment: -1 doesn't give any path info

Comment: If Java is installed and environment variables are set, do you need path?