# how to create an installer that requires java class path for execution

Tags: jvm, exe, java, izpack

i have made an installer with izpack 
for my java desktop application ... 
after installation my launcher.bat file needs java build path to be set for execution ..
when i add java build path it works fine  ....

but .., how could i make it work in all the systems i install ..

any answer or methods would really help ..

look at my batchfiles 
(i have shown you the batch files where **i have not added java bin path**)

**caller.bat**

```
set CLASSPATH=$INSTALL_PATH\src\cs.jar;$INSTALL_PATH\lib\log4j-1.2.15.jar;$INSTALL_PATH\lib\swt.jar;.;$INSTALL_PATH\lib\swt-debug.jar;.;

set PATH=$INSTALL_PATH\src\cs.jar;$INSTALL_PATH\lib\log4j-1.2.15.jar;$INSTALL_PATH\lib\swt.jar;.;$INSTALL_PATH\lib\swt-debug.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_33\bin;.;

java com.acti.conversionsupport.browser.SWTBrowserImpl
```

**swtbrowser.bat**

```
set CLASSPATH=$INSTALL_PATH\src\cs.jar;$INSTALL_PATH\lib\log4j-1.2.15.jar;$INSTALL_PATH\lib\swt.jar;.;$INSTALL_PATH\lib\swt-debug.jar;.;

set PATH=$INSTALL_PATH\src\cs.jar;$INSTALL_PATH\lib\log4j-1.2.15.jar;$INSTALL_PATH\lib\swt.jar;.;$INSTALL_PATH\lib\swt-debug.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_33\bin;.;

java com.acti.conversionsupport.browser.CallerSocket
```

**launcher.bat**

```
 cd \
 cd "$INSTALL_PATH"

 nircmd exec hide caller.bat


 nircmd exec hide swtbrowser.bat
```

when i execute launcher after adding java bin folder to the classpath ....things works fine both of my task get executed ..but what could i do for other systems ..**how could i make things work fine everywhere** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may consult the Windows registry to obtains the JRE installation path as shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930383/jre-installation-directory-in-windows/3930458#3930458)

To consult the registry from batch [see this link](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntregquery.php).