# Reliable way to find JRE installation in Windows bat file to run java program

Tags: java, batch-file, window

When installing the latest JRE 7 on Windows, it no longer adds the command `java` to the system path. So just calling `java --version` in bat file fails in that case (despite that Java from java.com is installed).

**What's a reliable way to find the java command installation directory in a windows bat file?**

I've seen it in the following locations:

- `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe`
- `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe`
- Not tried JRE 8 yet.

Note: if there are multiple, I 'd like the default (or the latest - I don't care).

Comment: See here, there is a batch script: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930383/jre-installation-directory-in-windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is installed, ask windows where it is

```
@echo off 
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Where to find java information in registry
    set "javaKey=HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment"

    rem Get current java version
    set "javaVersion="
    for /f "tokens=3" %%v in ('reg query "%javaKey%" /v "CurrentVersion" 2^>nul') do set "javaVersion=%%v"

    rem Test if a java version has been found
    if not defined javaVersion (
        echo Java version not found
        goto endProcess
    )

    rem Get java home for current java version
    set "javaDir="
    for /f "tokens=2,*" %%d in ('reg query "%javaKey%\%javaVersion%" /v "JavaHome" 2^>nul') do set "javaDir=%%e"

    if not defined javaDir (
        echo Java directory not found
    ) else (
        echo JAVA_HOME : %javaDir%
    )

:endProcess 
    endlocal
```

Comment: What does `setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion` do? Is it needed?

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet, `setlocal` protects the environment variables from changes made inside the `setlocal/endlocal`, `enableextensions` is usually not needed as extensions are enabled by default, but it is just a good habit to ensure you will have not problems. `disabledelayedexpansion` is included just to prevent some parser errors when assigning values to variables when the values include exclamations marks (that will be parsed/interpreted/removed)

Comment: I tried this on 1 Windows machine (win 8) with the latest java of java.com (1.7), and the registry key was not `HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment`, but `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment` instead. **Is there any way to deal with any and all of these deviations?**

Comment: Apparently Wow6432Node is the only common deviation, so an extra check for that regkey solves it. Thanks :)

Comment: [Here is the bat script that we're currently successfully using](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-distribution/src/main/assembly/scripts/runExamples.bat) (which is based on this answer).

Answer (score 1):

This is how to find them.

```
Dir c:\java.exe /a/s
```

searches entire drive.

You can put it in a for loop. (in `for` loops `%A` becomes `%%A` ina batch)

```
@for /f "tokens=1-8 delims=/ " %A in ('dir "c:\program files\java.exe" /a /s^|findstr /i /v /r "DIR VOL \(s\) Listed"') do echo day %A month %B Year %C Name %G
```

This finds it and puts day month year into seperate variables.

```
For /?
dir /?
findstr /?
```