# How to know path of my java compiler

Tags: java

I am a novice Java programmer. I checked existence of Java in my system, I executed `Java` command in command prompt and I found multiple options. When I executed `java -version` command, I got below resutl:

```
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode, sharing)
```

But, I am not able to locate the Java compiler path. How can I locate the path?
I am using Windows XP 32 bit system.

Below is the result of `PATH` command execution:

```
PATH=C:\RailsInstaller\Git\cmd
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.8.7\bin
c:\oracle\ora92\bin
C:\Program Files\Oracle\jre\1.1.8\bin
C:\WINDOWS\system32
C:\WINDOWS
C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Roxio Shared\10.0\DLLShared\
C:\Program Files\Windows Imaging\
C:\Program Files\Enterprise Vault\EVClient\
C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13
C:\software\mysql-proxy-0.8.3-win32-x86\bin
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13
```

Comment: In Which environment? Linux? Windows?

Comment: Linux: `which java`. Windows: `echo %PATH%` and check all directories listed there to find the first one which contains `java.exe`.

Comment: $ which java in linux

Comment: possible duplicate of [unix "which java" equivalent command on windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454424/unix-which-java-equivalent-command-on-windows)

Answer (score 4):

You can use either:

Windows - `where java`

Linux - `which java`

As @ursitesion mentioned there was no reason to upvote this. Carelessly I did not read to the part where OP mentioned Windows XP.

Take a look at this users post and upvote his awnser:
[Is there an equivalent of 'which' on the Windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/is-there-an-equivalent-of-which-on-the-windows-command-line#answer-304441)

Comment: I executed `Where java` command on command prompt. But, I got below result - `'where' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Answer (score 1):

Path to Java Compiler: directory BIN in your Java/JDK 1.7.045. Compiler version: type in command line

```
javac -version
```

Comment: This is not my answer. Don't know why this answer has been upvoted?

Answer (score 0):

in linux `whereis java`

in windows `echo %PATH%` and you will see some `/bin/java` somewhere

and the java compiler is named `javac` and it should be in the same folder where `java` ( `/bin/java` ) is

this is the method I would think of... but I saw that someone already provided a better solution for windows

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from below post

[unix "which java" equivalent command on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454424/unix-which-java-equivalent-command-on-windows)

As per the above post, I need to execute the below command in command prompt:

`for %i in (java.exe) do @echo.   %~$PATH:i`

I executed and got below result :

`C:\WINDOWS\system32\java.exe`

I searched in my system and found that java.exe exist in `c:\windows\system32\`

Answer (score 0):

To locate the Java Compiler Path you have to see the environment Variable.

> You can see the "JAVA_HOME" and "PATH" environment variable and that
>   shows the path to the java compiler.

Comment: No, I did not get the path of `JAVA` when I executed `PATH` command. I have updated my question with the result of PATH command execution.