# Finding the path of installed program from MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, path, installation

Can I find out from the MATLAB command line what is the installation path of specific program?
Or can I find the path for a registered program (Windows reg equivalent)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the <del>DOS/</del>bash command `which`, e.g.,

```
!which matlab
!which notepad
```

(Or use `system` instead of the `!`.)

EDIT: It seems that there isn't a direct equivalent in Windows.  I had cygwin installed on the (Win XP) machine I tried it on, and the command succeeded.  Alternatively, take a look at these answers on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/is-there-an-equivalent-of-which-on-windows) and [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/49104/handy-tool-to-find-executable-program-location).

Comment: @richie-cotton: I'm using windows xp, so I get 'which' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 3):

This won't be 100% reliable, but this will get the right answer most of the time:

```
function p = findOnSystemPath(f)
p = '';
path = getenv('path');
dirs = regexp(path,pathsep,'split');
for iDirs = 1:numel(dirs)
    tp = fullfile(dirs{iDirs},f);
    if exist(p,'file')
        p = tp;
        break
    end
end
```

Sample usage:

```
>> findOnSystemPath('runemacs.exe')

ans =

C:\Program Files (x86)\emacs\bin\runemacs.exe
```

Depending on your OS, you might be able to get this information from the system directly:

`which` is available on Unix systems and Windows systems with [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) installed:

```
>> [~,p] = system(sprintf('which "%s"',f))

p =

C:/Program Files (x86)/emacs-mw-a/bin/runemacs.exe
```

`where` is available on [Windows 2003 and later](https://superuser.com/questions/276736/which-versions-configurations-of-microsoft-windows-include-the-where-command):

```
>> [~,p] = system(sprintf('where "%s"',f))

p =

C:\Program Files (x86)\emacs-mw-a\bin\runemacs.exe
```

And in some cases, you can pull this information from the registry using [winqueryreg](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/winqueryreg.html), for example:

```
>> notepadEdit = winqueryreg('HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT','Applications\notepad.exe\shell\edit\command')

notepadEdit =

C:\Windows\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE %1
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what you know about the OS and what properties your program has.

On Linux I usually do something like:

```
[error, path] = system(sprintf('which "%s"',programName));
```

It doesn't look pretty and it's far from portable (I suppose it will not work on Windows, perhaps only if you install Cygwin or something similar). It's far easier in Unix since most executables are accessible from the "path" (the environment variable "path"), while in Windows most executables are either stored in the Windows directory (which is in the default path, so they are found) or in a Program Files directory which is not as far as I recall.

Error = 0 when the program is found and `path` then obviously contains the path to the executable.

For Windows I guess you can search all directories for the program, but that might be somewhat tedious.

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB is not really designed to be used as a tool to search files anywhere on the drive. That's a task best left to the OS, and what Egon suggested is what you should be doing. Simply replace `which` with the equivalent in DOS (you should know this already, else just ask another question in the MS-DOS/Windows tag. It probably has already been answered.).

If you are *really* hell bent on using MATLAB to search the drive, then you can do the following

```
addpath(genpath('C:\')); %#' I am not sure which way the slash is
which filename
```

Beware, the first step *will* take a while.

Comment: Nice way to circumvent the limits of Windows :-).
Just a few additions: on Windows it's a backslash (`\ `), but I think MATLAB can handle a normal slash as well on both Windows and Unix as a path separator (you can also take a look at `filesep` for the correct one)

On the other hand, by adding your whole drive to the MATLAB path, my biggest fear is that the performance of MATLAB will suffer a lot (especially when you call functions that do not exist).

Comment: @Egon: I know... I was just pointing out to the OP that making MATLAB do an OS' job is kinda unreasonable.

Comment: I know you know. But I wanted to point it out very clearly to the OP that you might not only end up with a performance hit once by running that code but possibly every time you try to access a file (e.g. .m-files).

Comment: @Egon: You're right, I should've mentioned that to the OP. Thanks for doing that :)