# Matlab "addpath" doesn't work for .exe?

Tags: matlab, path, environment-variables

I'm running a script in folder A, which needs to call functions and .exe's inside folder B. I used `addpath(C:\...\B)` in the script, but only the functions (.m) in B are reached successfully, not the executable files (.exe). However, both .m and .exe are accessible if I run the script under folder B and select "add to path". Why doesn't `addpath` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addpath modifies the matlab search path, not the os search path which is relevant for executables. Either switch to the directory:

```
cd ('C:...\B')
system('example.exe')
```

or refer the executable with the full path

```
system('C:...\B\example.exe')
```

You may also modify the windows path variable and add `C:...\B`

Comment: Thank you. I ended up with 
    cd ('C:...\B')
    myfun()
    cd ('C:...\A')
since more than 1 .exe's are called.

Comment: Use something like`p=pwd;cd ('C:...\B');myfun();cd(p);` instead. It returns to any previous set working directory.

Answer (score 1):

As @Daniel pointed out, I believe you're confusing the OS level path variable with the Matlab [`path`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/path.html). You might look into the [`getenv`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getenv.html) and [`setenv`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setenv.html) functions. In particular, you may be able to obtain you Windows path via

```
getenv('PATH')
```

There are also lower-level ways to do this via calls to [`system`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html). Finally, you might also find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818545/finding-the-path-of-installed-program-from-matlab) helpful and maybe [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552416/how-can-i-find-the-users-home-dir-in-a-cross-platform-manner-using-c) too.