# Find where python is installed (if it isn't default dir)

Tags: python

Python is on my machine, I just don't know where, if I type python in terminal it will open Python 2.6.4, this isn't in it's default directory, there surely is a way of finding it's install location from here?

Comment: I just found mine in C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36

Answer (score 190, accepted):

In unix (mac os X included) terminal you can do

```
which python
```

and it will tell you.

Comment: @Ned check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/is-there-an-equivalent-of-which-on-windows

Comment: @Foo Bah: yes, thanks.  Did you see mine was the accepted answer there? :)

Comment: @Ned no offense but I had actually intended to point to the answer that had the most upvotes (it used CMD primitives :)

Comment: -1: Definitely not the best answer here. There are both single line and multiline solutions that work on every answer.

Comment: This is also not the best answer because many, many more times often than not, your `python` executable is a symlink. `which python` will, in all probability just point to `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`, which really isn't helpful.

Comment: An alternative to looking for Windows equivalents to these commands is to install a bash shell on Windows. The "which python" command works when run in Git Bash on Windows.

Comment: "which python" works for me on Windows in Bash but not a command prompt. "where python" works in a command prompt.

Comment: is there any command or method of module to find from python file where the python interpretor is?

Answer (score 260):

`sys` has some useful stuff:

```
$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84297, Aug 24 2010, 18:13:38) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'c:\\Python26\\python.exe'
>>> sys.exec_prefix
'c:\\Python26'
>>>
>>> print '\n'.join(sys.path)

c:\Python26\lib\site-packages\setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg
c:\Python26\lib\site-packages\nose-1.0.0-py2.6.egg
C:\Windows\system32\python26.zip
c:\Python26\DLLs
c:\Python26\lib
c:\Python26\lib\plat-win
c:\Python26\lib\lib-tk
c:\Python26
c:\Python26\lib\site-packages
c:\Python26\lib\site-packages\win32
c:\Python26\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
c:\Python26\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
c:\Python26\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode
```

Comment: When I type `sys` in Python it says it is not defined... what is going on there? Thanks.

Comment: @Learnaholic - You need to `import sys` first.

Comment: Pythonic! This is an OS agnostic answer and doesn't require access to command line. This worked well for me since I only have access to the Python Interpreter.

Comment: Please accept this answer as it is multi-platform and doesn't need access to the shell/cmd!

Comment: This also works better when you have multiple pythons installations and access them through py -2 or py -3 for example, since 'which python' will probably display only one

Comment: For Python 3, I had to use `print('\n'.join(sys.path))`

Answer (score 130):

Platform independent solution in one line is

Python 2:

```
python -c "import sys; print sys.executable"
```

Python 3:

```
python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"
```

Comment: Worked great on windows! If you're on  python 3 you'll have to change it to `print(sys.executable)`

Comment: the python 3 version should work on python 2 regardless, as the parentheses are just treated as a token

Answer (score 59):

For Windows CMD run: `where python`

For Windows PowerShell run: `Get-Command python`

Comment: This one is really nice 

Comment: doesn't work in PowerShell for some reason

Comment: I updated the answer to include powershell

Comment: If this also included `which python`/ `which python3` for UNIX/Linux, this would be the best answer. +1 anyways.

Comment: Don't know why this one isn't first in the list. Simple, easy, and does exactly what was asked. Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

Have a look at `sys.path`:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.path)
```

Comment: this one should be the recc approach on windows

Comment: sys.path returns a list of directories. I specifically need the one that is Python\Python310 (or whatever version). How do I rule it out to get the correct one?

Answer (score 16):

On UNIX-like systems, you should be able to type `which python`, which will print out the path to `python`. The equivalent in Windows Command Prompt is `where python`, and `Get-Command python` in Windows Powershell.

Another (cross-platform) method is to type this into IDLE or REPL (type `python` into your terminal):

```py
import re
re.__file__
```

Or in one line from your terminal:

```
python -c "import re; print(re.__file__)"
```

This will print the path to the `re` module, consequently showing you where the `python` command points to. You can put any other module that you know is installed, and the path will point to that module, also giving you the path to `python`.

Comment: What if they don't have the re module.

Comment: How do you get a Python interpreter without re? :)

Comment: Build your own, I know I have in the past.

Comment: And forgot where you put it, did you? ;-)

Comment: This is how I know that /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/ is the same directory as /usr/bin?

Comment: If you don't have the `re` module, then try it with a module that you **do** have. Anything you're expecting to be in the `lib` subdirectory should work, such as `os` (which is pretty essential).

Comment: @Karl  Yup.  I just picked something that came standard and assumed anyone reading it would be able to figure out you could substitute any standard module.  My mistake. ;)

Answer (score 10):

To find all the installations of Python on Windows run this at the command prompt:

```
dir site.py /s
```

Make sure you are in the root drive. You will see something like [this](https://www.webucator.com/blog/2015/12/how-to-find-all-your-python-installations-on-windows/).

Answer (score 9):

If you are using wiindows OS (I am using windows 10 ) just type

```
where python
```

in command prompt ( cmd )

It will show you the directory where you have installed .

Answer (score 3):

For Windows Users:

If the `python` command is not in your `$PATH` environment var.

Open PowerShell and run these commands to find the folder

```
cd \
ls *ython* -Recurse -Directory
```

That should tell you *where* python is installed

Comment: Windows only and on top of that requires PS.

Comment: @misantroop I dare you to find an instance of windows without powershell; unless you're running Windows Server 2003, it will have powershell

Comment: Not natively on XP and all of the versions derived from it. Installing software to determine where Python is located seems overkill.

Comment: @misantroop yes. XP is a version derived from Windows Server 2003. You will be lucky to find a Windows machine that doesn't have powershell.

Comment: Thanks @KolobCanyon - this is helpful

Answer (score 3):

1. First search for PYTHON IDLE from search bar
2. Open the IDLE and use below commands.

   import sys
   print(sys.path)
3. It will give you the path where the python.exe is installed. For eg:
   *C:\Users\\...\python.exe*
4. Add the same path to system environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, search for "python", then right-click on it and click "Open file location".

Answer (score 1):

##### OS Independent Solutions:

Nothing new here, but might be worth mentioning...

Unless you have changed the default installation path for `pip`, just open a shell and type `pip list -v --version`, the executable will then be found in the directory before `Lib`.

```
# pip list -v --version

Package  Version Location                            Installer
-------- ------- ----------------------------------- ---------
pip      23.3.1  C:\lang\Python312\Lib\site-packages pip
venvlink 0.5.0   C:\lang\Python312\Lib\site-packages pip

# OR use

# python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"
C:\lang\Python312\python.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Run below command

```
where python
```