# What is the shebang line for .pyw files?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, shebang

I've been writing a Tkinter program and I don't want the console to show, so I used a .pyw file. However the program ran with an error that said the program could run usr/bin/python3, so I removed the shebang line, and it worked, but do I need a shebang line? Or should I keep it as is.

Comment: Does it work with the shebang? -No. Does it work without it? -Yes. Do you need a shebang line? -Provided that it works without one, you probably don't.

Answer (score 1):

**If it works without the shebang line:**

- Your computer found a version of Python to run it (likely in your ["PATH" environment variables](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)).

**If it didn't work with the shebang line, either:**

- You made a typo, or
- You gave it an incorrect path to your version of Python

**Make sure you know exactly where Python is installed on your device:**

- [Mac/Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767283/find-where-python-is-installed-if-it-isnt-default-dir)
- [Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/is-there-an-equivalent-of-which-on-the-windows-command-line)

(To anyone simply copy-pasting what you see in tutorials - without a good grasp of what it's doing: Try googling terms like "shebang line" and figure out what they might be doing behind the scenes)

Comment: I believe OP is asking about shebang for executing the file in background process (the way it works in Windows for `.pyw` files)