# My command prompt doesn't seem to recognize "pip". What can I do to get it to work?

Tags: python, cmd

I'm trying to use Tweepy and am trying to install it but typing in 
"pip install tweepy" results in:

> 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file."

This is a windows 10 pc. I've been trying this on the command prompt. I've tried changing the path in the windows settings.

'

> C:\Users\Orlando>pip install tweepy 'pip' is not recognized as an
>   internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I expect it to begin installing Tweepy but instead I get this error message.

Comment: did you install pip to begin with? if you are using python3 then you should use pip3 not pip.

Comment: Did you add pip to the Windows Environment Variables?

Comment: Welcome @Orlando to SO, try this command ```py -m pip install tweepy```

Comment: @vaku This finally got it to start installing, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Go to environment variables
and add to `PATH` the following paths

```
...\PythonXX\
```

and

```
...\PythonXX\Scripts\
```

where `...` is your Python installation directory

Answer (score 0):

The reason that pip is not working on your pc is that `ENVIRONMENT PATH` is not set to your python script directory you can add that simply like:

- Press WIN+R and type in `SystemPropertiesAdvanced` click on `Environment Variables` button
- then search for path in `System variables` and add a new entry as described by @bleand, 
  i.e., `YOUR PYTHON INSTALLATION DIRECTORY\Scripts`

> you can find your `PYTHON INSTALLATION DIRECTORY` by [This stackO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6767762/8071073)

I this did't works then try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows) SO answer for installing pip in your system

Try reading [Command line and environment](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m) for getting the reason why `py -m pip install PACKAGENAME` works..

Thanks...