# How to run 32 bit binaries on AWS lambda using Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, x86

AWS Lambda Python 3.8 runtime says it can [execute 32bit libraries](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/09/amazon-linux-2-now-supports-32-bit-applications-and-libraries/). I have a 32 bit executable which was built in C. When I execute the following code - I get:

`wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32`

I tried the same on Amazon Linux 2 docker image. The error I get is same. possibly python gives CDLL a 64 bit instance.

Using the 32 bit docker image from ubuntu `32bit/ubuntu:16.04` it works fine.

```
import platform 
print(platform.architecture())
```

I will have to invoke Python in 32 bit architecture.

C Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo() {
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Python Code:

```
import ctypes

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    libhi = ctypes.CDLL("my32bitlib.so")
    libhi.foo()

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }

lambda_handler(None, None)
```

Comment: Did you try this code on Amazon Linux 2 (on EC2) before moving to Lambda/Python3.8?

Comment: Yes, I tried it on Amazon Linux 2 docker image - I get the same error!

Comment: OK, I would investigate it further on EC2 before you move back to Lambda. I'm not sure what, if any, restrictions there are around supported 32-bit binaries and libraries on AL2.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/09/amazon-linux-2-now-supports-32-bit-applications-and-libraries/ just means they've installed `gcc-multilib` and so on so the system has `/usr/lib32/*.so` available, so you can run 32-bit binary executables.  And those 32-bit executables in 32-bit processes can load 32-bit libraries.

They haven't invented any magic that lets you use a 32-bit library *from a 64-bit Python process*.  The CPU will be in 64-bit mode when executing user-space code in that process, and thus it won't be able to correctly execute 32-bit x86 machine code in a 32-bit library.

If they had switched the normal `/usr/bin/python` over to being a 32-bit executable, that would have broken 64-bit libraries.

**I think you're being overly optimistic about what that news announcement means;** it's probably not relevant for you because your program is written in Python.  You can't mix 32 and 64-bit code and regular `python` is still a 64-bit program.

---

They might possibly have installed a 32-bit build of Python that you could use if you want to load legacy 32-bit libraries in a Python program.  Maybe look for a `python32` directory or binary, if that's what they called it?  But don't be surprised if you don't find anything.

If so, change the `#!/usr/bin/python` line at the start of your script to whatever the right path is.  Or install your own 32-bit Python build in /usr/local and use that.

Comment: What changes do I have to do in my python script so that I am able to run the 32 bit library?

Comment: @user923227: Just the path in the `#!/usr/bin/python` line.  Change that to a the path to a 32-bit Python interpreter, if there is one installed.

Comment: No. This did not solve the issue. It is getting the same error. It is still invoking the `64 bit` python interpreter, from `platform.architecture()`

Comment: @user923227: Then you picked the wrong path, or your python scripts are being invoked by something that runs `/usr/bin/python` on them without looking at the #! line.  (So you should change whatever runs them.)

Comment: [Looking for the python path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6767329/923227) - I found there is only `python3.8` installed!

Comment: @user923227: You might have to install a 32-bit build of Python yourself.  It wouldn't surprise me if there is no 32-bit `python` already installed on AWS.