# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4' even though I have installed BeautifulSoup4 properly with pip3 (Windows)

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, pip, windows-10

Python version: 3.9.5

pip version: 21.1.1

BeautifulSoup4 version: 4.9.3

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('home.html', 'r') as html_file:
    content = html_file.read()
    print(content)
```

I have been trying to use the BeautifulSoup4 library but it just won't work. In `vscode`, it shows the indication that bs4 is there when I do CTRL+click on bs4 written in Code. But it still gives `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'`

I have installed it properly with pip3 as shown in the below screenshot

[image]

The version of python I am using in VS Code is shown in below Image
[image]

Just a side note. I also used some other packages such as Camelcase and that one worked fine. Idk why this one is not working properly. I couldn't find any proper related solution for it in the existing solutions for it.

Comment: Have you tried to run python from cmd and import bs4? That will help you figure out where exactly the problem is. Also - any chance you are using a venv on vscode?

Comment: I think no I am not using any virtual enviroment .. I have Anaconda installed by as I have shown u in Screen shot from Vs Code . I am currently using default installed python3.9.5

Comment: @Y.R.  I just did run python3 from cmd and then types `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup4`  and it gave me `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'`

Comment: I did Ctrl+F5 on VSCode and it runs code but when I do `python3 main.py`  it doesn't work and gives the error. Idk what is going on.

Comment: I would suggest debugging using python on cmd.
Do you have a few versions of python3 installed? Maybe packages are being downloaded to the wrong python dir.
Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767283/find-where-python-is-installed-if-it-isnt-default-dir

Comment: hey. the issue got resolved. thanks allot. ur first hint was really helpful cause I figured it out for what might be the cause of it. it was because of `python` and `python3` paths and the python among installed I was using.

Comment: Great :) happy that helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had python3 installed 2 times.. 1 from the Windows store and the other from python exe file. `python3` command referred to windows installed python3 and  `python` referred to exe file installed python3.  BeautifulSOup installed via pip3 was linked to the `python` command instead of `python3`  so that was the reason it wasn't working.

after checking for paths of `python` and `python3` everything got clarified and the problem solved thanks to the hint given by @Y.R in the comments section of the main post.