# How to get Jupiter Notebook to run when given a zsh: command not found: jupyter error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have been using Jupiter notebook for a long time and it has worked fine. Today when I tried to use the 'jupyter notebook' command in terminal to open it, I got 'zsh: command not found: jupyter'. I have tried reinstalling Jupiter notebook and it says its already installed. I don't know what could have gone wrong, the only thing that has changed since it was working is that I installed command line tools for Xcode, but I don't know if that would cause this.

Edit: I'm on a Mac with Monterey installed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using anaconda, miniconda or conda in general, you would need to activate with `conda activate <env_name>` for Windows or `conda source <env_name>` for linuxOS, and this will require a restart of the terminal if you are doing this for the first time.
Default env name is `base`.

If the problem persists (or you aren't using conda) check if the pathing is correctly pointing towards python where jupyter exists / is installed. (Check which location of python [is used check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6767329/10985412))

Comment: I spent a lot of time searching online, and only this did the trick for me.