# Error while running python script in power bi desktop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, powerbi

'm trying to use python scripting in power bi. I am referring documentation: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-python-visuals) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767283/find-where-python-is-installed-if-it-isnt-default-dir);

also confirming of installing appropriate packages in the folder,
[image]

Identifying directory using `where python` and my installation directory is `C:\USERS\ABC\ANACONDA3`

[image]

I am using an example script provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-python-visuals)

```
    import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'Fname':['Harry','Sally','Paul','Abe','June','Mike','Tom'], 
    'Age':[21,34,42,18,24,80,22], 
    'Weight': [180, 130, 200, 140, 176, 142, 210], 
    'Gender':['M','F','M','M','F','M','M'], 
    'State':['Washington','Oregon','California','Washington','Nevada','Texas','Nevada'],
    'Children':[4,1,2,3,0,2,0],
    'Pets':[3,2,2,5,0,1,5] 
}) 
print (df)
```

Please help in resolving below error,
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You have an import for `pandas`; have you actually installed it? If so, how?

Comment: @esqew please review original post. Yes, I have pandas installed

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you don't have panda installed.

You could first check in your C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages that you indeed have the panda package available.

If not, you can install it using this command :
`py -m pip install pandas`

Comment: I have anaconda installed in another location: C:\Users\abc\Anaconda3
'm using this directory for power bi setting. It should be able to run the script, but getting an error

Now, the pandas is located under 2 locations: 
1. C:\Users\abc\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages
2. C:\Users\abc\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\astropy\io\misc

Comment: please review original post. Yes, I have pandas installed