# Capture screenshots for a Ruby on Rails application in Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Currently I am cursed with trying to develop a Ruby on Rails app in Windows and then deploy to Linux. I am looking for a gem/plugin that will allow me to capture screenshots and feed them back to the user. WebSnap looked promising but I keep running into issues (error: Could not locate wkhtmltoimage-proxy executable) even though I have the bat files in the path and in just about any folder I can think of.

So, does anyone have a suggestion for a library that will work on Windows that will allow me to do this? Or in another vein a way to resolve the wkhtmltoimage-proxy executable issue?

Code:

```
format.png {  
  html = render :action => "show.html.erb", :layout => "application.html.erb"

  Rails.logger.debug("html: " + html.inspect)
  snap = WebSnap.new(html,  :format     => 'png',
                            :'scale-h'  => nil,
                            :'scale-w'  => nil,
                            :'crop-h'   => nil,
                            :'crop-w'   => nil,
                            :quality    => 100,
                            :'crop-x'   => nil,
                            :'crop-y'   => nil )

  send_data snap.to_bytes,  :filename     => "dashboard.png",
                            :type         => "image/png",
                            :disposition  => 'inline'
}
```

Comment: websnap doesn't look like it will work on Windows, there's a few unixisms in the source.

Comment: @BenoitGarret thanks for the help. I will make a stab at making it windows friendly here.

Comment: that's the right decision :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem appears to be that WebSnap's developer just didn't think to make it work on Windows. You can spot the problem right [in the source](https://github.com/siuying/websnap/blob/master/lib/websnap/websnap.rb#L65-67):

```
def initialize(url_file_or_html, options={})
  # ...
  raise NoExecutableError.new if wkhtmltoimage.nil? || wkhtmltoimage == ''
end
# ...

def wkhtmltoimage
  @wkhtmltoimage ||= `which wkhtmltoimage-proxy`.chomp
end
#                       ^-- derp
```

Basically to find the path to the executable, WebSnap calls `which`, which is a *nix command not available on most Windows machines.

You have a couple options here:

1. You could patch it yourself to work correctly (and [submit a pull request to the developer](https://github.com/siuying/websnap), thereby becoming an unsung hero to fellow Windows developers who would encounter this same issue in the future).
2. You could file an issue with the developer and hope that s/he fixes it quickly enough for your project.
3. You could check out the answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/is-there-an-equivalent-of-which-on-windows) for getting a `which`-equivalent command on Windows.
4. You could run your app under [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), which bundles most common Linux commands.
5. You could monkey-patch or subclass the library, something like:

   ```
   class MySnapper < WebSnap::Snapper
     ExecPath = '/absolute/path/to/wkhtmltoimage-proxy'

     def wkhtmltoimage
       super

       @wkhtmltoimage = ExecPath if @wkhtmltoimage.nil? || @wkhtmltoimage.empty?
       @wkhtmltoimage
     end
   end

   # And then instead of WebSnap::Snapper.new, use MySnapper.new
   ```
6. You could invoke wkhtmltoimage directly. That is assuming a Windows binary comes bundled with [wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltox](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) or you can build it yourself. It's short on docs but if you scroll down to 13 Apr. 2011 [on this page](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/wiki/Usage) you'll see a useful comment, or you could try to infer the correct parameters from WebSnap's source.

I'm most in favor of Option 1 because it both solves your problem and helps out other devellopers. However, Option 5 is probably the quickest and easiest--that is, unless there are more parts of the gem that only work on unixy platforms.

Comment: Jordan, thank you. I will go for option one. The which thing was throwing me; I thought it was something about the setup not working right; never occurred to me it was a *nix based command.