# how to use subproces.Popen correctly on windows xp?- shows windowserror 2 while accessing npm

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, npm

I am trying to run an existing python code, and having issues with it.

This program required npm program installed and which is installed at C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm in my computer. When I run the following code, as a part of the whole program, it throws errors.

```
def popen_results(args):
   proc = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
   return proc.communicate()[0]

def installed():
   """docstring for npm_installed"""
   return popen_results(["which", "npm"]).strip()
```

This is the complete stack of the error thrown--

```
Checking for node and dependencies
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "deploy\deploy.py", line 344, in <module>
    main()
  File "deploy\deploy.py", line 287, in main
    if not check_deps():
  File "deploy\deploy.py", line 201, in check_deps
    return npm.check_dependencies()
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Sunil\workspace\khan\src\deploy\npm.py", line
38, in check_dependencies
    if not installed():
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Sunil\workspace\khan\src\deploy\npm.py", line
13, in installed
    return popen_results(["which", "npm"]).strip()
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Sunil\workspace\khan\src\deploy\npm.py", line
8, in popen_results
    proc = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\python25\lib\subprocess.py", line 594, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\python25\lib\subprocess.py", line 822, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: Looks to me like it can't find the `which` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with martineau, it is unable to find which.  The script may have been written with the assumption it was going to be run in a unix environment which would most likely have the "which" command available and in the default PATH.  Since it looks like you're running this on Windows, I don't think it's going to work.

It looks like there is some alternatives to which on Windows though, discussed here: [Is there an equivalent to which on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/is-there-an-equivalent-of-which-on-windows)