# Where I can find java version?

Tags: java

When I run command "java -version" I can see jdk version. But where it stores physically?

Comment: Where does it store what? (And why do you want to know that?)

Comment: I should find the registry keys: "SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit" "CurrentVersion"

Comment: @LesyaMakhova Why would you expect it to be in the Registry? As cagcowboy says in his answer, it's built into the `java` executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess/expect that the java version would be built into the executable.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you mean "where are the binaries for Java stored" in which case the answer  depends on your operating system.

**On linux** (or most OS X), typing

```
which java
```

will tell you where the main java binary is physically located

**On Windows** it's a bit harder. See [Is there an equivalent of 'which' on the Windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/is-there-an-equivalent-of-which-on-windows) for a good discussion, or for quick check, type into a commad prompt:

```
echo %PATH%
```

and look for Java-related entries, or better still:

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
```

to see if that's set. This will be the base directory for your JRE.