# How to determine path to php.exe on Windows - search default paths

Tags: php, python, windows, path, sublimetext

I'm currently developing a couple of plugins for Sublime Text 2 on OS X and I would like to make them cross platform, meaning I have to find out if and where `php.exe` is installed.

Right now I call `/usr/bin/php` in Python, which obviously works only on OS X and Linux:

```
phppath = '/usr/bin/php'<br>
pluginpath = sublime.packages_path() + '/HtmlTidy/tidy.php'<br>
retval = os.system( '%s "%s"' % ( phppath, scriptpath ) )
```

But on Windows, there seems to be no definitive default path for php.exe. The more I googled for it, the more possibilities showed up. So far I think I would have to check each of the following paths for existence:

```
c:\php\php.exe
c:\php5\php.exe
c:\windows\php.exe
c:\program files\php\php.exe
c:\wamp\bin\php\php5\php.exe
c:\xampp\php\php.exe
```

That's already quite a collection, but what I'm asking for is either a *complete* list covering all possibilities - *or* another way to figure it out that should be as robust as checking each possible path.

So if you have php.exe installed in some place other than these, please leave a comment with your path and I will add it to the list above.

Besides, there seems to be `php.exe` and `php-cli.exe`. I guess it would be OK to loop through each possible path. Check first for php-cli.exe, check for php.exe, and take the first match. Is that correct or is there a better practice?

Comment: I would just search for it in the Windows PATH, and then if it's not there, prompt the user for it.  Your list can never be complete.  And, what if the user has multiple paths to a php.exe? I have 5 or 6 php.exe right now.

Comment: Take a look for the `PHPRC` environment variable. It contains the directory where `php.exe` is located. It's often available on windows systems.

Comment: you might be able to search the registry, but I'm no expert on it so I ccouldn't say how.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If the user has added PHP's bin folder to the system `PATH`, then you should just be able to try and execute `php -v` to check that it's present.

If you want to obtain the full path to the PHP executable and the target system is [Windows Server 2003](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2003) or later (so [Windows Vista](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Vista), and [Windows 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7)) then you could use the `WHERE` command, i.e.:

```
C:\> where php.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\WAMP\bin\php\php5.3.5\php.exe
```

Also see possibly related question: *[Is there an equivalent of 'which' on the Windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/is-there-an-equivalent-of-which-on-windows)*.

If you are really desperate to find *any* file on the user's computer, you could try executing the equivalent of a `find` - but it's going to be *slooow*!

```
C: && cd \ && dir /s /b php.exe
```

Comment: `where` doesn't find my `php.exe`. Indeed it seems only to look in PATH and the current directory.

Comment: @Kos could you tell us, where *your* php.exe actually is?

Comment: Thank you JonnyReeves, `where` would probably do the job, but the first answer on the link you posted led me to this python script which seems to deal quite well with PATH and PATHEXT: http://nedbatchelder.com/code/utilities/wh_py.html - since the plugin for Sublime Text 2 is in python, I'm going to use some lines of code from it to minimize calling external programs.

Comment: @Mat a regular WAMP installation like mentioned before, `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.9\php.exe`

Comment: `where /?` says "By default, the search is done along the current directory and in the paths specified by the PATH environment variable."

Comment: in windows, you can check your path if it has php or not with:
`$env:Path.Replace(';', "\`n") | findstr "php"`

Answer (score 9):

On powershell or commad prompt
php -r "echo PHP_VERSION;" gives the version

See other PHP constantas:
https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.constants.php

to answer your question

**php -r "echo PHP_BINARY;"** gives the full path to php.exe

if needed, to remove the php.exe

**php -r "echo str_replace('php.exe', '', PHP_BINARY);"**

Answer (score 6):

From PHP 5.4 and later, you can use the PHP_BINARY constant.

Comment: For all us noobies out there, it would be useful if this was updated with a longer explanation.

Comment: `echo PHP_BINARY;` but it's giving me nothing on Linux.

Comment: In my case it returns C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe which does not execute a file, while C:\xampp\php\php.exe does

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
C:\xampp\php\php.exe
```

It should work if your [XAMPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP) instance is on *D:* or *E:*. You change it accordingly from *C:*.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way for you to find out where the php.exe is stored. In C:, click the search bar and search for "php.exe". Then, there will appear an application called php and click it. Then, cmd will open and in the cmd tab it will say php.exe at the end. That's where your php.exe is and you can put the link address of the file in VS Code.

Answer (score -3):

Try

```
echo PHP_BINDIR;
```

It works. I tested it on macOS as with PHP 5.6.

Comment: Question is about Windows not Mac. This does not work

Comment: Good to know. Thanks for sharing your experience. What system configuration did you try it on? Php vercsion and so on...