# NodeJs exec-php module, php is not a command

Tags: php, node.js, ajax, exec, call

I am trying to call a `php` file from my `nodejs` file. I have installed and required the `exec-php` module and it has been install fine. The error I am getting is:

```
{ Error: Command failed: php C:\Users\***\Desktop\nodejs\xxchat11\node_modules\exec-php\lib\php\cli.php -pC:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-129647qzlx6s.gh55ewmi.tmp -rC:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-12964
7pid95t.8vpiizfr.tmp
'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
   at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:204:12)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:886:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:342:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:501:12)
  killed: false,
  code: 1,
  signal: null,
  cmd: 'php C:\\Users\\***\\Desktop\\nodejs\\xxchat11\\node_modules\\exec-php\\lib\\php\\cli.php -pC:\\Users\\***\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp-129647qzlx6s.gh55ewmi.tmp -rC:\\Users\\***\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp-
129647pid95t.8vpiizfr.tmp' }
```

My `php` file is:

```
<?php
$hashes = array('md2','md4','md5','sha1','sha224','sha256','sha384','sha512','ripemd128','ripemd160','ripemd256','ripemd320','whirlpool','tiger128,3','tiger160,3','tiger192,3','tiger128,4','tiger160,4','tiger192,4','snefru','snefru256','gost','gost-crypto','adler32','crc32','crc32b','fnv132','fnv1a32','fnv164','fnv1a64','joaat','haval128,3','haval160,3','haval192,3','haval224,3','haval256,3','haval128,4','haval160,4','haval192,4','haval224,4','haval256,4','haval128,5','haval160,5','haval192,5','haval224,5','haval256,5');
function hash($method. $plaintext){
  if(in_array($method, $hashes)){
    $hashed = hash($method, $plaintext);
    echo 'The '.$method.' hash, for the string `'.$plaintext.'` is: '.$hashed;
  } else {
    echo "Method not found! Please type !help to see the list of supported methods.";
  }
}
?>
```

In my `nodejs` file I call the php file by:

```
var execPhp = require('exec-php');

app.get('/hash.php/:method/:text', function(req,res){
  execPhp(__dirname+'/hash.php', function(error, php, output){
    console.log(error);
    //php.hash(req.params.method, req.params.text, function(err, result){
        //res.send(result);
    //});
  });
});
```

Also, within my `index` file I am running the `app.get()` by:

```
$.get('hash.php/'+method+'/'+plaintext, function(data) {
    $chat.append('Chatbot: <strong>'+data+'</strong><Br />');
});
```

Have I done anything wrong within this code that will affect the error? Also, If there is a more efficient way of doing this please let me know as I have spent a couple hours already trying to figure out how to get these files to work smoothly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[exec-php](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exec-php) takes 3 parameters:

1. `String`. Path to user php file.
2. `String`. **Path to machine php bin file.**
3. `Function`. Callback function after creating exec-php object.

You're missing the second parameter, the path to php, that's why you're getting that error.

```
execPhp(__dirname+'/hash.php', 'PATH_TO_PHP', function //...
```

To get php location:

**Windows:**

```
C:\>where php.exe
```

**Linux**

```
which php
```

Check this answer: [How to determine path to php.exe on windows - search default paths?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9645545/how-to-determine-path-to-php-exe-on-windows-search-default-paths)

Comment: Where would I be able to find the PHP bin folder? I have never seen it.

Comment: I think I am having to install it onto my computer, as the where php.exe returns nothing. I will get back to you when I have installed it

Comment: You don't have php installed?

Comment: I have just downloaded and move it to C:/ but still nothing, http://php.net/get/php-7.1.4.tar.bz2/from/a/mirror

Comment: Ahh, I don't know why but the where php.exe command doesn't work for me. I found it within my xampp folder in c:/. Thank you for helping me :)