# Multiple Different PHP version is not working

Tags: php, xampp

In my system I have 2 xampp servers installed.

In one xampp server php version is 5.6 and second xampp server php version is 7.3 .

In both server paths, only php 5.6 version is shown at command line.
Supported 7.3 is not working.
In both server path php 5.6 displayed.

So when I use Composer and Laravel always fetch php 5.6.

Please help me to solve this problem..

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywNZa.png]

Comment: Changing PHP version on xampp does not affect on php cli version. You have to change php path on PATH.

Comment: you can use [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10) to change path variable of your system

Comment: @Maitrik can you say if my answer solved you problem?

Comment: @Luiz Vaz,  at one time two environment variable is not working, either work PHP 7 variable else PHP 5 working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to run the **CLI** version of **PHP**.
So it's all about your **PATH** variable.

Windows looks for paths in **PATH** variable to know where are executables.

By the way, the `php.exe` it's inside `c:\xampp\php` directory.
And, the 7.3 would be inside `c:\xampp_7.3\php` directory.

And of course, the **PATH** variable has something like `PATH=c:\xampp\php;...`
That's why 5.6 version is always picked.

Run command `c:\set PATH` and will show your settings like:

```
Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Python38\Script
s\;C:\Python38\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windo
ws\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\xampp\php;...
```

To work, with changing PATH variable you need to move to you path where is composer.phar and composer.json and run:

```
c:\> cd \composer\file\
c:\composer\file> \xampp_7.3\php\php.exe composer.phar install
```

More information here:
[How to determine path to php.exe on Windows - search default paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9645545/how-to-determine-path-to-php-exe-on-windows-search-default-paths)

**UPDATE:**

As an alternative, you can set two environment variables and use them like below:

```sh
c:\> set PHP56="c:\xampp\php\php.exe"
c:\> set PHP73="c:\xampp_7.3\php\php.exe"

c:\> %PHP56% -v
PHP 5.6.40 (cli) (built: Jul  2 2019 15:10:36) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies

c:\> %PHP73% -v
PHP 7.3.10 (cli) (built: Jul  2 2019 13:01:33) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```