# Find the exact location of a file which is in the PATH

Tags: path, directory, dos

Is there a simple command find out the exact location of a file which can be executed from anywhere because it is the PATH? 
Searching all the directories which are set in the path in order to find it out.. is not very efficient especially if the path contains a lot of directories and all of them are possible candidates...

Thank you

Comment: Can you give an example please? Which operating system?

Comment: Maybe the standard utility `which`?

Comment: DOS ..lets say you type foo.bat... and the foo is executed but it is not in the current directory (probably becuase it is in PATH). How can you find out where the foo file is?

Comment: See Is there an equivalent of 'which' on windows?
http://stackoverflow.com/q/304319/318716.

Comment: @Joseph Indeed there is! The equivalent is "where", That commands searches to find the given file in all the directories that are in the path! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps:

> WHERE [/R dir] [/Q] [/F] [/T] pattern...
>
> Description:
>       Displays the location of files that match the search pattern.
>       By default, the search is done along the current directory and
>       in the paths specified by the PATH environment variable.

See also the previous SO question [Is there an equivalent of 'which' on the Windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/304319/318716).