# I can run sqlite3 command but its not included in Environment Variables?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm just curious as in how is it possible that i can execute sqlite3 command when i can't locate the sqlite3.exe file?

Tried to locate it in program files, not found. Tried to locate it in Environment Variables, also not found. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Just because *you* can't doesn't mean the system can't :-)

The [`where.exe`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/is-there-an-equivalent-of-which-on-windows) command can be used to see where the executable is being found:

```
> where sqlite3.exe
```

(The executable should be located in the current working directory *or* as a file in one of the paths listed in the [`%PATH%`](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them) environment variable.)

Answer (score 1):

Its command line shell, which doesnt come implicitly with SQLite framework,
You can download it from [here](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite-shell-win32-x86-3071501.zip)
For more variety of download look [here](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html)