# How can I tell which executable is being called from my path?

Tags: windows, cmd

I installed several utilities to give Unix commands to my Windows shell so that I could use `ls` and `grep` and others.  I changed my system's path so many times I don't know which version is getting called when I call a command.  So when I do

```
ls *.txt
```

I don't remember which version of `ls` is being called.  How can I find out which one is being called, without going through every entry in my path?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an equivalent of 'which' on the Windows command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/is-there-an-equivalent-of-which-on-the-windows-command-line)

Comment: The directories that are earlier in the path statement will be the first ones searched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this already has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/), but for reference, the command `where` does what I need.

```
where ls
```

will print to stdout where the executable ls.exe can be found on my path.