# Get the location of executables in PATH

Tags: java, windows, system-paths

I would like to use the `rar.exe` path in Java. This is needed to unpack rar files from within my Java application without using a library.

I figured I'd require the user to add the program files folder for Winrar to the `PATH` system variable.

All I need to know now is how to get the full path to the `rar.ex`e file.

What I've got now is this:

```
//Split all paths
String[] paths = System.getenv("Path").split(";");
for(String value : paths)
{
    if(value.endsWith("Winrar"))
        System.out.println(value);
}
```

However, there is no way of me knowing if the user installed Winrar to say `C:\Programfiles\Winrarstuff`. Is there a way to get the location of `rar.exe`, or do I have to manually scan every folder in the Path string for the location?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `where` on Windows Server 2003+ which is roughly equivalent to `which` in *nix, however you can get similar behavior for other windows environments using the code found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/304441/1427161

Answer (score 1):

When the path to `rar.exe` is in the PATH environment variable, you can simply invoke `rar.exe` from any file location. That means you can also call it via `Runtime.exec(...)`. If the return code is other than 0, the process cannot be started, e.g. because Winrar is not installed:

```
public static boolean checkRar() {
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c rar.exe");
    try (BufferedReader reader =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // parse line e.g. to get version number
        }
    }
    return (proc.waitFor() == 0);
}
```

Comment: My first code snippet was simply executing "rar.exe" does NOT respect the PATH environment. Instead "cmd /c rar.exe" must be called (windows only!) and it is required to read the input from the process, otherwise it will not terminate.

Comment: Why would you execute `rar` through `cmd` here?

Comment: @Joey if you don't do it that way, the PATH environment variable is ignored, so you'd have to specify the full path to rar.exe.

Comment: So there is no portable way of executing programs in the `PATH` in Java? That sounds odd.

Comment: Yes, but on the other hand, rar.exe is not portable too, so one will have to port the code anyway.