# I have changed JAVA_HOME and PATH correctly but I see wrong java version. Why? (windows)

Tags: java, windows, installation

I used java 7 but now I need to use java 6.

I installed jdk 6 on my PC.

My cmd:
[image: shell]

Why do I see java - version - 1.7 ?

What do I forgot made?

### update for user2881767

[image]

### update for TomaszDz

```
c:\>where java
C:\Windows\System32\java.exe
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_38\bin\java.exe
```

Comment: Open cmd again and check, if you have installed Java in C:\Windows or C:\Windows\System32.

Comment: @TomaszDz please provide commands for check

Comment: Use `where java` - 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/is-there-an-equivalent-of-which-on-the-windows-command-line

Comment: @TomaszDz please provide link to concrete answer - it is very long topic

Comment: Open cmd and type: `where java`. It should find java.exe (1.7) and you'll know, where it is installed. --- http://stackoverflow.com/a/304447/1679995

Comment: @TomaszDz please read update

Comment: My first comment :) I knew it, that you have installed java in `system32` directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the java at 
`C:\Windows\System32\java.exe`

It should never have been unzipped at that directory, anyways. In fact, you should probably go ahead and delete everything else java-related in system32, java isn't a system binary.

Comment: where does it come from there?

Comment: not sure what you mean, where does java come from? it comes from oracle, I guess.

Comment: How could java got into this folder ?

Comment: it had to have been installed there by something or someone

Comment: I single user of this workstation. Only I can use this PC. Thus I installed java to this folder. But I am sure that I don't make it

Comment: ok, so you installed java to your system32 folder. I would HOPE that you didn't make that folder, it should already exist, it contains binaries critical to the functioning of your windows OS :)

Comment: I removed only java.exe javaw.exe and 1 more file

Comment: That's fine, the only file you needed to remove was java.exe anyways, because it took precedence on your environment PATH. I would remove javac, too, though, you don't want that to accidentally conflict.

Comment: I tryed to type **where java** from pc my colleagues and everyone has java in **windows/system32** but everyone doesn't know how it installed there

Comment: This seems to be a corporate PC. It is standard for corporate IT departments to have a windows imaging system so that every computer has the same exact installation of windows out of the box. In any case the JRE and its dependencies should not be in system32, it just causes confusion in the long run when you want to switch java versions.

Comment: I try to check it at home.

Comment: At home I see same situation

Comment: then the java installer probably puts the executables inside of system32 for convenience of use from the shell(doesnt need to modify PATH in order to access java.exe) , but when you updated java you probably just updated your c:/program files/java to the latest version manually and did not update those convenience binaries. this is not of significance.. if you need to switch between java versions the EASIEST way is to only have your java.exe for a certain version located in its own directory, that way you can change your PATH to each bin folder without confusion.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set class path as ClassPath=JAVA_HOME/bin.
Check version of Java being picked after setting classpath.