# Windows Batch File - Batch File stops executing mid way after a command that takes a while to complete

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, batch-processing, windows-7-x64

Following are the contents of the file "vs.bat"

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat"

call path.bat

dea usev bis 

cd ana

call b-env-i.bat
```

When I execute this batch file, execution stops after the following step.

```
dea usev bis
```

Can anyone please help in pointing out what went wrong here and how I can get all the commands to execute. Note that the aforementioned command (dea usev bis) works fine (both in the batch and if executed separately). dea is the name of the executable and "usv bis" are runtime parameters to the "dea" exe.

I'm running Windows 7.

---

**Clarification:**

When I run vs.bat, after the third call "dea usev bis" has executed successfully, the batch file stops executing further. That is both the following calls (which are part of VS.bat) don't get executed

cd ana

call b-env-i.bat

Note that the call "dea usev bis" takes around 20 secs to execute, both when run individually and when run as part of the script.

---

**Update:**

I've tried paxdiablo's suggestions, with the following results:

```
[C:\dea]for %i in (dea.cmd) do @echo %~$PATH:i
ECHO is on.

[C:\dea]for %i in (dea.bat) do @echo %~$PATH:i
ECHO is on.

[C:\dea]for %i in (dea.exe) do @echo %~$PATH:i
C:\dea\bin\dea.exe

[C:\dea]where dea.exe
C:\dea\bin\dea.exe
C:\dea\bin\dea.exe.1
C:\dea\bin\dea.exe.ia64
```

When I run it explicitly via the following, I still encounter the same issue

```
c:\dea\bin\dea.exe usev bis
```

And, as I said earlier, changing the script to `call dea` does not fix the issue either.

Is there anything else that I can try?

Comment: Are you sure that "dea" is an exe file `dea.exe`? Based on your problem, I could bet that "dea" is a Batch file: `dea.bat`, so it also requires a CALL command: `call dea usev bis`, as paxdiablo indicated in his answer...

Comment: dea.exe is failing to complete.  Is that the problem?  Place a `pause` command on the line after it and see if it reaches that line.

Comment: If you read the OP carefully, you'll see that I've already mentioned that the call "dea usev bis" does complete successfully.


"Note that the aforementioned command (dea usev bis) works fine (both in the batch and if executed separately)."

Answer (score 17):

It looks like you're trying to call another batch/script file which, if you leave off `call`, will simply be *chained* to rather than called (chained to, in this context, means it doesn't return). I'd suggest changing that line to:

```
call dea usev bis
```

By way of example, consider the scripts `go2.cmd`:

```
@echo off
echo %1
```

and `go.cmd`:

```
@echo off
call go2 1
go2 2
echo 3
```

Executing `go` will only give you:

```
1
2
```

because the `go2 2` line chains to, rather than calls that script. The `call go2 1` line, however, works fine.

And, even if you *have* a `dea.exe` file, that does not necessarily mean it's the one being run. Your script calls `dea` so leaves the choice as to what actually gets run to the shell (searching the path, trying different extensions and so on).

To *check* whether or not the thing you're actually calling is a batch file or not, you can do the following. First, execute the following commends:

```
echo %PATH%
for %i in (dea.cmd) do @echo %~$PATH:i
for %i in (dea.bat) do @echo %~$PATH:i
for %i in (dea.exe) do @echo %~$PATH:i
```

(or I think you can just use `where dea*` if you're running Win 7+, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/is-there-an-equivalent-of-which-on-the-windows-command-line/304441#304441) for details).

This will show you if there is a `dea.cmd/bat/exe` in your path, and tell you *where* in the path the relevant directories are. If there is a script version, it may exist in the path *before* the `exe` version. You can simply examine your `%PATH%` environment variable to figure out which directory comes first.

Second, if you have the `exe` in `c:\dea\bin`, try running that *explicitly* from your script with:

```
c:\dea\bin\dea.exe usev bis
```

If that returns okay, it adds support to the fact a script version is being used instead.

Thirdly, you could just change the script as suggested (add `call`) and see if that fixes it. If it *is* referencing a script, that will fix it.

---

If *none* of those work (and this appears to be the case based on your response that `dea` is definitely an `exe` file), you need to start looking into *exactly* where the failure occurs. This can be done by placing an `echo` statement in between every single line so that you can see what's causing the issue. In other words, something like:

```
echo DEBUG a & time <nul:
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat"
echo DEBUG b & time <nul:
call path.bat
echo DEBUG c & time <nul:
dea usev bis 
echo DEBUG d & time <nul:
cd ana
echo DEBUG e & time <nul:
call b-env-i.bat
echo DEBUG f & time <nul:
```

That will both give you timings for the things that *do* work and hopefully make it obvious what's *not* working.

Comment: OP specifies DEA is an EXE... but he could be wrong

Comment: I just double checked, DEA is an exe, and is present in the C:\DEA\bin
folder

Comment: @user3594917, the existence of an `exe` does not necessarily mean that's the one being used. I've updated the answer with instructions on how to confirm this.

Comment: @paxdiablo, If It's not clear from the OP let me repeat, every command that I've referenced in the vs.bat file ( in the OP ) works if executed individually and further we also know that the command "dea usev bis" is what fails as it takes around 20 seconds to complete and the batch file grinds to a halt. Is there something that I'm missing from the steps that you've suggested ?

Comment: @user3594917, there's a big difference to your original contention "execution stops" and "takes about 20 seconds". Please confirm that this problem is either a "doesn't complete at all" or "takes longer in the batch file" one.

Comment: @paxdiablo, I've updated the OP with the following 

**Clarification:**

When I run vs.bat, after the third call "dea usev bis" has executed successfully, the batch file stops executing further. Note that the call "dea usev bis" takes 20 secs to execute, both when run individually and when run as part of the script.