# ImageMagick, "which" is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: imagemagick

I just installed ImageMagick on my windows machine so I can use it with the paperclip gem with RUby on Rails. When I try to run "which convert" into the command prompt, it returns a **'which' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

I am relatively new to command prompt and still trying to learn as much as I can. What is wrong with my command and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 9):

The command is right. The OS is wrong. 
`which` is a unix command not a windows one.

See the [equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/is-there-an-equivalent-of-which-on-the-windows-command-line) Windows command

Comment: is there a way to call that command within the windows command prompt? I just need to know where the convert utility is installed on my computer

Answer (score 1):

Just use the following command on Windows:

```
where package_name
```