# java -version and javac -version showing different versions

Tags: java

I have `java 7` and `java 8` both installed on my windows system under `C:\Program Files\Java`

In the environment's path I specified the path of `java 7` like this.

`%JAVA_HOME%/bin` where `JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17`

But when I type `javac -version` it shows `javac 1.7.0_17` which makes sense

but when I do  `java -version` it shows

```
java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)
```

[image]

**Any idea what may be the problem here?**

**Edit** The installed folder :
[image]

**And one more thing `echo %PATH%` has only one occurence of `JDK` that is for `java 7` and no occurence for `JRE` found in it.**

Comment: Are you sure you installed the Java 8 **JDK**, and not just its **JRE**?

Comment: See if `echo %PATH%` contains the JRE folder of Java 8 before the JDK folder of Java 7

Comment: set your jre7 bin location path at first like - set PATH=%JAVA%\bin;%PATH%  so it will pick your jdk7 bin path first.

Comment: @Mureinik please if you dont mind check the edit of the question

Comment: @ChrisMartin if you read the query properly you can most probably find what is the problem

Comment: @TheConstructor `echo %PATH%` has only one occurence of JDK that is for java 7 and no occurence for JRE found in it.

Comment: @M.Sharma - Please paste the actual output of `echo %PATH%` ... run from the same command shell that you are running `java` and `javac` in.  This *has to be* a problem with your search path.

Comment: @StephenC please check the latest image now

Comment: Java versioning is the biggest problem in java ecosystem especially after they started producing new version every 6 months. I am wondering why nobody solved this problem? In node and npm there is nvm, but here not too many options besides alternatives in linux..

Answer (score 37):

The issue is occuring most probably because you have a **JRE** in your `PATH`, before your **JDK**. This usually happens when we add JDK in the `PATH` and do not remove previously added JREs. Thus when you do `java` it points to the JRE and when you do `javac` it points to the other version/JDK (since the JRE does not have a `javac` in it)

If you don't have any JREs in your path, then you can copy your `%JAVA_HOME%` and paste it first in your path variable (make sure its before the `system32` path).

A possible reason for why this works is [explained in this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/391977/fix-java-version-mismatch-in-windows):

> JRE also puts a `java.exe` to `c:\Windows\System32`, that's how first command is resolved. Second command is resolved by the `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin` entry in your `PATH` variable.
>   If (and when) you are developing from the command prompt, you have to adjust the `PATH` variable so that `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin` is before `c:\Windows\System32`.

Comment: `echo %PATH%` shows only one occurence of JDK and that is for java 7 and no occurence for JRE found in it.

Comment: Ok so I just found that `c:\Windows\System32\java.exe` date-modified is same as the java 8 installation date so I guess that the java.exe in `c:\Windows\System32` is of java8 how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Yes, which i guess confirms that its taking java.exe of java 8 from system32, I have written in my answer, `You can copy your %JAVA_HOME% and paste it first in your path variable (make sure its before system32 path)` , this way it will get both jdk and jre of java 7 before system32 version that is of java 8

Comment: +1 not an ideal solution though but indeed thanks for the help :)

Comment: Be notice USER path will append to SYSTEM path. However the `C:\Windows\System32` locates in SYSTEM path, you have to add `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` into it which will pollute my SYSTEM path. GUI installer sucks.

Answer (score 10):

Go to Environment Variables in your windows machine.
In User Variables : Make sure to set
- Your user variable "JAVA_HOME" value to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-xxxx\bin"
  where "jdk-xxx" is the version of your jdk.

In System Variable :
- Add same "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-xxxx\bin" value to "Path" variable.
  make sure to move the added value on top of all values.

Now try running java -version and javac -version.
worked for me. :)  [Here i've linked my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRmMf.png)

Answer (score 7):

It's all about **$JAVA_HOME** system variable

In my case

for **Windows**

(moving jdk8 -> jdk9 -> jdk11)  I had a garbage
left by jdk8 in  PATH (before JAVA_HOME:"C:\path\java11")

so I just     **remove**  `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath_jdk8` from **system variables**

// or place it below javapath_jdk11

for **MAC** 
edit .zshrc to have

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-???.jdk/Contents/Home"
```

Answer (score 6):

Ok, as you said that you have no JRE on your path, I assume that [`where java` (if you have Windows 7)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/304447/1266906) will give you `C:\Windows\System32\java.exe`.

## Changing the `java` running

Try using the Java-Settings Dialog from the control panel to change the Java System Version, which is currently active. This should change the version `java -version` is returning. If this does not work, you will probably need to reinstall the Java version of which you want to run the `java` command, specify the path explicitly, write you own wrapper (which works if you are in the same directory as the wrapper) or place the JRE path before `C:\Windows\System32\` onto your path (don't know if last option really is a good one).

A wrapper could look just like this:

```
@"C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" %*
```

and you can either name it `java.bat` (where it will work if you are in the same directory or put it in `PATH` before `C:\Windows\System32\java.exe` or you could name it `java7.bat` and put it anywhere on you path to be able to run the Java 7 JRE if you desire to do so.

A wrapper is also a good option if you want to change the `JAVA_HOME` when running.

## Changing the `javac` running

If you want to run a different `javac` hit `Windows + Pause` and open the system dialog to change the `PATH` so it contains the path to your JDK 8 instead of your JDK 7. You will need to restart your command line for changes to show.

Comment: I just found that c:\Windows\System32\java.exe date-modified is same as the java 8 installation date so I guess that the java.exe in c:\Windows\System32 is of java8 how to resolve this problem without tempering the path?

Comment: @M.Sharma Second paragraph of my answer. Guess reinstalling the JRE 7 could be the best option. For me there is now way to change the System JRe through the Java-settings-panel also I think that this was once possible.

Comment: java path sometimes really can be a pain in the ass

Comment: So that means next time if I uninstall and reinstall java 8 again I'll face the same problem unless I keep my desired path before `c:\Windows\System32`

Comment: @M.Sharma that would probably be the case. Maybe you really should consider using full path or a wrapper.

Answer (score 3):

To resolve such kind of environment issue I always believe on command whereis, 
To do the same in windows download [whereis.exe](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3784/Whereis-for-Windows) then set in path and execute the command

> > whereis java.exe
> >
> > whereis javac.exe

You will easily find the exact path from which location java is being called in environment as well about javac.

Comment: Yes but in other OS version its not there so those developers can use it easily.

Comment: Where you could also try [`for %i in (java.exe) do @echo %~$PATH:i`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/304441/1266906) which is probably not as fancy, but does not require you to add new programs to your system.

Answer (score 2):

Please check that you have replaced "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;" with %JAVA_HOME%/bin in the PATH variable. This did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

**FOR LINUX USERS**

if java and javac are showing different versions, then you can easily set them to the correct or same versions

**step 1**

```
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

output :

```
    Selection    Path                                          Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac   1111      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac   1111      manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac    1081      manual mode
```

this will show the following message:

> start(*) indicates the ***javac*** version that your system is using.
> You can change it by selecting your required version.

**step 2**

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

output :

```
      Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode
```

Now again you can select the version you want to run for ***java***.

This way you can ensure that java and javac are having the same versions.

Answer (score 1):

A side note with the accepted answer. I couldn't leave the trail of java-1.8.0, but I have installed java 17 and want java "17", so, I placed java 17 bin path in the first place (top most ) of path variables, Home variable and user variable, after that when I type in cmd : `java -version`, it also show  java-1.8.0, then I restart cmd, restart Intellij ide, then I type `java -version`, then it shows :

```
java version "17" 2021-09-14 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17+35-LTS-2724)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17+35-LTS-2724, mixed mode, sharing)
```

and when I type :

```
C:\Users\dell>javac -version
```

It shows :

```
javac 17
```

Here is My path variables ScreenShots and command window :

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar case but both command `javac --version` show the old version of sdk. It shows "javac 11.0.8" even it should be "javac 19" which is the new version just be installed.

1. Go to search bar > type > env
2. click menu "Edit the system environment variables"
3. Advanced tab > click on button "Environment Variables..."
4. Under "System Variable" > select "Path" > click "Edit"
5. Looking for Java path such as "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin"
6. Move the path using "Move Up" or "Move Down" button to the position before "%SystemRoot%\system32" Path
7. OK > OK

Try the command agian.
Hope this may help you guys.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it *is* true that in order to deal with mismatching versions we need to modify the PATH variable, and the **`where`** command (at least, in Windows) is very handy in finding out which program gets picked first.
There's, however, a twist:
when you look at the contents of yout PATH var after running, for example,

```
echo %path% > path.txt
```

you should be aware of the fact that PATH is actually composed of TWO sections: one is **System PATH** and the other is **Current User PATH**, and it is *System Path* that gets evaluated first but printed last.
So simply placing a path to your, say, brand-new JDK in front of everything will be useless as long as there's another place with older version somewhere in the **System PATH**.

This particular problem is especially common when you have entries such as

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath
```

in your **System PATH**. Simply move them to the tail of your **Current User PATH** section to make these entries the last ones within the search queue.

Answer (score 0):

Check your JAVA_HOME variable under environment variables in Windows machine. Make sure It is pointing to the version that you want.
Next check java jdk path added into your "path" environment variable. Make sure It is the version that you want, Otherwise change this to your JDK version path and then move this to the top of the list of values in path variable. This should mark your desired version as the first choice and all issues will be resolved. I did so, and everything is good.

Answer (score 0):

I found my javac was pointed to a specific location called 'Eclipse Adoption' in my AppData directory within my 'User' folder. I didn't realize that it was in my PATH variable, so I simply removed it, and the problem was solved for me

Answer (score -2):

I guess when you are writing `javac`, it is getting the value from `jre7` which is currently being used by you for development purposes and when you write `java version`, it is getting the value of the `version` from the `jre8` which is currently being used by the installed applications on your system because your `JRE` of the system is mentioned before the `jre7` which you are using for development

Comment: This is a comment than an answer.

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera OP's question is **not about some error** in code,its about explaining some fact