# java version value is different with java and javac

Tags: java

I am getiing java versions different with java command and javac command

```
java -version

java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode, sharing)

javac -version


javac -version
javac 1.6.0_18

where java

C:\Windows\System32\java.exe
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\bin\java.exe
```

path is set  to 1.6 but it is picking 1.8 
suggest me how to get this resolved.

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem. Any code compiled with Java 1.6 can run on Java 1.8.

Comment: eventhough in path it is set to 1.6 but showing 1.8 from where it is picking 1.8

Comment: refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25074017/java-version-and-javac-version-showing-different-versions)

Comment: You have both the 32bit and 64bit installations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is cause by the extremely annoying habit of the Java installer to copy `java.exe` and`javaw.exe` to  `C:\Windows\System32\java.exe` when you choose to install the "public jre" (but because that's the JRE, of course no `javac.exe` is copied).

And because `System32` comes early in the `PATH` `java.exe` from there will be used (and before the regular JDK installation will no be searched for `java.exe`). But as there is no `javac.exe` in the JRE, that in turn is used from your JDK.

The public JRE is only needed for the browser Java plugin. In 2014 I consider the Java plugin to be dead and (I think) Oracle should change the JDK installer to not install that automatically.

Actually I consider this behaviour a bug to be honest. No installer should copy files to `system32`

Comment: It is really anonying because even if you dont have version-x in your environment path it show you version-x because java.exe of version-x exists under C:\Windows\System32

Comment: Note that what is copied to `system32` is just a stub and has no particular Java version. Which java it actually starts is governed by the "current Java version" setting in the Registry.