# Error loading class: Bad major version number

Tags: java

I'm trying to compile this java file manually (for learning purposes):

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

So I saved file and run:

```
C:\Users\maikon.neitzel\Documents\Java>javac Test.java
```

No errors.

Next step:

```
C:\Users\maikon.neitzel\Documents\Java>java Test
Error loading class Test: Bad major version number
```

So I did my research and found things about the PATH.

So I did it:

This are the variable for my user:

```
JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102

PATH: %JAVA_HOME%\bin

JRE_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_102
```

And there is another PATH for the system where I put the same:

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

This is on Windows 10, and with the last java 8 version.

Versions:

```
C:\Users\maikon.neitzel\Documents\Java>javac -version
javac 1.8.0_102

C:\Users\maikon.neitzel\Documents\Java>java -version
java version "1.1.8.16"
```

From where this java 1.1.8.16 is coming?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: There must be something else on your `PATH` called `java`, before the `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` entry. There might be another `Path` variable too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25074017/java-version-and-javac-version-showing-different-versions this might help.

Comment: Solved. I found a `c:\orant\jdk\bin` **AFTER** `%JAVA_HOME%` at system variables. So I figured I needed `%JAVA_HOME%` defined not only for my user, but at system variables too. Thank you guys.

Comment: @MaikonNeitzel please close the question, it is still marked as unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I found a `c:\orant\jdk\bin` **AFTER** `%JAVA_HOME%` at system variables. So I figured I needed `%JAVA_HOME%` defined not only for my user, but at system variables too.