# How To Make Scrapy Use Python 2.7.10 rather then 3.4.3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, scrapy

I've two versions of Python installed. 3+ for Django and 2+ for Scrapy. I can use whatever version I want using the following method:-

```
py abc.py #for 2.+ use
py -3 abc.py  #for 3.+ use
```

The problem is that when I try to make a project with Scrapy

```
scrapy startproject news
```

How can I explicitly mention or force scrapy to use 2.+ python version. Currently, it is using 3.+ version. I can confirm this because it gives me an error at a certain "twisted" package, that Scrapy uses, which is only for python 2.+

**Update:-**

I'm using Windows environment.

**Update:-**

```
>where.exe scrappy
C:\Python34\Scripts\scrapy.exe
```

Comment: How have you installed Scrapy? What is the output for `which scrapy`?

Comment: @alecxe I'm using Windows environment.

Comment: Ok, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/is-there-an-equivalent-of-which-on-the-windows-command-line :)

Comment: @alecxe Thanks. It says, `C:\Python34\Scripts\scrapy.exe`.

Comment: Thanks! This is the key problem, you've installed Scrapy into your Python 3.4 environment.

Comment: @alecxe Thanks, I found it. If you can make answer of your comment, then I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual problem is that you have Scrapy *installed into the Python 3.4. environment*.

Install it into the Python 2.7 environment. If installed, you can check if `scrapy` points to the 2.7 "Scripts" directory or call it directly from Python 2.7 "Scripts".

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is type : 
`#!/usr/bin/Python2.7`

at the start of the text file
It will execute using Python 2.7

Comment: I'm using Windows environment.