# react-router peerDependencies error

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-router

I'm trying to install react-router but I get the following error.

```
$ npm install react-router
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency react@0.13.x included from react-router will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "react-router"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package react does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-addons-test-utils@0.14.0-rc1 wants react@^0.14.0-rc1
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-router@0.13.4 wants react@0.13.x
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-bootstrap@0.25.2 wants react@>=0.13

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\ReactApps\good start\npm-debug.log
```

The package.json for `react` in `node-modules` shows that  I use:

```
"version": "0.14.0-rc1",
```

Should I install an earlier version? It seems that 0.13.x might be a better supported version?

If that is the case, how can I install without messing up my current project?

---

After using

```
npm install npm -g
```

I typed `npm -v` and saw that the version in my project is still 2.11.13.
I figured that it might be a local version of NPM so I typed:

```
npm install npm
```

hoping to get the latest version updated locally, but still got 2.11.13 when I checked for the version.

```
comp-asus XXX64 /c/ReactApps/goodRouter/goodrouter (master)
$ npm -v
2.11.3

comp-asus XXX64 /c/ReactApps/goodRouter/goodrouter (master)
$ npm install react-router
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency react@0.13.x included from react-router will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "react-router"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package react does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-router@0.13.4 wants react@0.13.x

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\ReactApps\goodRouter\goodrouter\npm-debug.log
```

When checking globally I can see that it is updated:

```
$ npm list -g --depth=0
C:\Users\Roger\AppData\Roaming\npm

    ├── babel-eslint@4.1.3
    ├── bower@1.5.2
    ├── eslint@1.5.1
    ├── findup-sync@0.2.1
    ├── generator-angular@0.12.1
    ├── generator-karma@1.0.0
    ├── generator-meanjs@0.1.12
    ├── generator-polymer@1.1.0
    ├── generator-react-boilerplate@0.1.9
    ├── generator-react-webpack@1.2.12
    ├── grunt-cli@0.1.13
    ├── gulp@3.9.0
    ├── httpster@1.0.1
    ├── jspm@0.16.10
    ├── jsxhint@0.15.1
    ├── live-server@0.8.1
    ├── mean-cli@0.10.14
    ├── mocha@2.2.5
    ├── node-gyp@2.0.2
    ├── npm@3.3.5
    ├── react-tools@0.13.3
    ├── superstatic@2.2.1
    ├── tsd@0.6.4
    ├── typescript@1.7.0-dev.20150921 invalid
    ├── webpack@1.12.2
    └── yo@1.4.7
```

But how do I use the global version in the project?

So the problem persists but I do believe you put me on the right track.

---

```
$ where npm
C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm
C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd
C:\Users\Roger\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm
C:\Users\Roger\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm.cmd
```

So I should delete one of these?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is one of the major issues solved in `npm@3`. See https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6565 for details.

Updating `npm` is the right thing to do:

```
$ npm install npm -g
```

Comment: Thank you! Please see update if you can. I do not have enough rep to +1 but I do thank you.

Comment: @RogerDore Are you using some tool for managing Node versions, like `nvm`?

Comment: I am not familiar with Tools for managing Node versions. I will look up nvm right now.

Comment: @RogerDore No, I didn't mean that… There is another `npm` in your `$PATH` and `nvm` can be a source of this so I asked. You need to disable the other `npm` (move it or make it non-executable).

Comment: @RogerDore Can you find that location with `where npm` or other suggestions from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/?

Comment: Ok! Im not sure of wath I am doing now but it seems that there are two:
Made a new update.

Comment: @RogerDore So as it seems you are using `npm@2.11.13` from `C:\Program Files\nodejs` but your global install directory is `C:\Users\Roger\AppData\Roaming\npm`. That is why you can't update `npm` easily. Moving or renaming `C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm` (and probably `npm.cmd`, I'm not sure) should fix the problem.

Comment: By changing name as you suggested it now uses 3.3.5. Thank you!