# Locate "chrome.exe"

Tags: google-chrome, file-search

I have a macro that calls Chrome, however deploying this code on different machines is undermined by the full filepath for chrome being different on each machine. To mitigate this, I wanted to execute a one-time search for "chrome.exe" and to store the filepath as a variable. The below seems to work however the recursiveness generates a stack space issue (Run-time error 28).

This seems such a simple operation, and recursive searches are all over the usual forums, yet I cannot get it right!

```
Function Recurse(sPath As String) As String
Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim myFolder As Folder
Dim mySubFolder As Folder
Dim myFile As File
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set myFolder = FSO.GetFolder("C:\")
For Each mySubFolder In myFolder.SubFolders
    For Each myFile In mySubFolder.Files
        If myFile.Name = "chrome.exe" Then
            Debug.Print myFile.Name & " in " & myFile.Path
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Recurse = Recurse(mySubFolder.Path)
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Function

Sub ChromeSearch()
Call Recurse("C:\")
End Sub
```

Comment: I would say that if you are using linux you could use the `which` command, but then I saw the `C:/` ...

Comment: Just searched and found a [Windows type of which](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/is-there-an-equivalent-of-which-on-the-windows-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

Note you are passing in a parameter `sPath` to your recursive function.

You are then ignoring this parameter and searching the folder `C:\` with each call. Now you have a recursive function with no terminating condition, so of course you're going to get a stack overflow exception.

Simply replace

```
Set myFolder = FSO.GetFolder("C:\")
```

with

```
Set myFolder = FSO.GetFolder(sPath)
```

And replace:

```
Recurse = Recurse(mySubFolder.Path)
```

With

```
Recurse = Recurse(sPath + "\\" + mySubFolder.Path);
```

(Or however you concatenate folders in this language)

---

On the topic of finding Chrome.exe, you would save a lot of time if you first looked in in two places:

- "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe",
- (The environment variable LOCALAPPDATA) +
  "\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe"

Comment: Thanks @AndrewShepherd. 
The suggested change FSO.GetFolder(sPath) returns a "path not found" error.

Comment: @JonPotter - You must have to concatenate the sub path to the base path. I've added an extra line of code for you. (You'll probably have to modify it slightly - I don't even know what language you're working in :-)

Comment: Very much appreciate the help despite my school-boy errors. Its Excel VBA, which I'm reasonably adept at in most cases, however haven't touched VBA in years and this one's got right under my skin :|