# Unable to trigger protractor test cases from command prompt

Tags: protractor

I am unable to trigger protractor test cases from command prompt [which used to work earlier]. However when executed from webstorm, same protractor test cases are executed without any issue.

Executed below command in command prompt:

```
protractor ConfigFiles\protractor.conf.js
```

Above command used to trigger protractor test cases earlier now it infinitely prints "protractor ConfigFiles\protractor.conf.js" in the same command prompt window.

Comment: What is the output of `which protractor` (if you are [not on windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/is-there-an-equivalent-of-which-on-the-windows-command-line))?

Comment: I tried it only in windows.. dont have other machine to try it :(

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I had one batch file in the same directory which has the same command "protractor ConfigFiles\protractor.conf.js". I am unsure about the reason why it triggered an infinite loop but once I deleted the batch file and executed the command in cmd prompt, it worked as it used to.