# How to find the python installation path on windows?

Tags: python, windows

On windows 10 I have python installed and working, but not in the standard place `C:\PythonXY`.

How to find out the location of the python installation?

Comment: Why not search `python` on the windows search bar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `where python` in a console.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/304447/354577

Answer (score 5):

You can do this:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
C:\Python35\python.exe
```

Comment: This answer (or `sys.prefix`) is more generally useful for a novice that may only know how to run IDLE from the start menu. Possibly they need to know where Python is to add the directory to `PATH`, in which case where.exe will be useless.