# How can I run script.js in Eclipse console?

Tags: javascript, node.js, eclipse

Is it possible to do the same as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8FBx.jpg) in Eclipse what he is doing in Intellij IDEA? to run the javascript file in console?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To set up Eclipse to run JavaScript files:

1. In Eclipse, got to Run > External Tools > External Tool Configurations
2. Double click on Program to open a new configuration and name your new configuration (ex. Node_Config)
3. Figure out where you have node.js installed.  Paste the results in the 'Location' box in Eclipse. (If you haven't installed node, do so [here](https://nodejs.org/en/))

   1. **Mac:** in the command line, run `which node`.
   2. **Windows:** in the command line, run `where node`, or see [this for more/different windows advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/is-there-an-equivalent-of-which-on-the-windows-command-line/)
4. Fill in the following:

   1. Working Directory: ${container_loc}
   2. Arguments: ${resource_name}
5. Click apply, and then close.

Now, in the main Eclipse screen, find the play button with a red toolbox (next to the regular play button). When you have a js file open that you want to run, click this and it will be just like running it from your console using node.

Comment: I have node.js installed, but the command line gives Syntax Error when I try to run 'which node'.

Comment: I've pasted https://nodejs.org/en/ in Location box, but this config is still unavailable in Run menu options

Comment: it worked! I've put this C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe and it worked! thanks!

Comment: @Olga I'm so glad! Sorry about the `which node` command - that is mac specific command to find where you have node installed. I chould have asked what you are using. Would you mind marking this as answered?

Answer (score 5):

Since Eclipse Neon you can do that. I suggets you that you

- download [Eclipse Neon](https://eclipse.org/downloads/) and install **Eclipse JEE Neon** distribution.
- install [node.js](https://nodejs.org/).

With Eclipse JEE Neon, you will benefit with **Run As / Node.js Application** and even with **Debug As / Node.js Application**:

[image]

Comment: Such a simple solution. I wonder why no one appreciated it. Thx

Answer (score 0):

He is using WebStorm which is editor for Front-end dev from same company (JetBrains).

Comment: so is it possible for Eclipse?

Comment: Yes it's possible with Eclipse JEE Neon