# PHP shell_exec() SASS --update

Tags: php, sass

I am trying to execute `sass --update` via PHP `shell_exec()` function and get an error:

```
H:\SERVER\htdocs\path\to\project>sass --style compressed --update sass\:deployment\css\ 'sass' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

If I run the same command from the cmd manually - it works fine. The current folder is correct - checked with the `getcwd()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the command `sass` in a shell, your computer has to find the executable program called sass somewhere on your computer. To do this, it looks through a series of folders called your PATH. Your PHP server is most likely running with a different PATH than your command prompt, and as such, is not able to find the executable.

To fix this: From your command prompt, where `sass` DOES work, run this command: `which sass` (on Windows, instead use `where sass`)

That will tell you the exact location of sass (for example, it might be `/usr/bin/sass` or something like that). Once you have that value, replace "sass" in your PHP code with that entire location.

Comment: Err, is the command just 'which sass'? 
"'which' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: Oh huh, I guess on Windows you have to use "where" instead. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/is-there-an-equivalent-of-which-on-the-windows-command-line

Comment: Yes, that's it! It gave me the Path :)